# as3 dropTarget return instance not the name

Tags: actionscript

I was trying to put a sprite over another sprite and get the name of the drop target. When I use a loder in my sprite the result is not the name of the sprite, but his instance number. I will post the code below and hope that someone could help me. Thanks alot!

```
package 
{
import flash.display.*; 
import flash.net.URLRequest;    
import flash.net.URLLoader; 
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

public class dragAndDrop extends MovieClip
    {

    public function dragAndDrop() 

    {
        // constructor code

        var imagineDrag:Sprite =  new Sprite;
            imagineDrag.x = 150;
            imagineDrag.y = 150;
            var fundalLoader:Loader = new Loader(); 
            var fundalLoaderURL:URLRequest = new URLRequest("butStartActiv.png");
            fundalLoader.load(fundalLoaderURL);
            imagineDrag.addChild(fundalLoader);
            imagineDrag.name = "Tinta";
            addChild(imagineDrag);

        var target1:Sprite = new Sprite();
            target1.graphics.beginFill(0xCCFF00);
            target1.graphics.drawRect(265, 100, 125, 125);
            target1.name = "casuta1";
            addChild(target1);


        var imagineDeTras:Sprite = new Sprite;
            imagineDeTras.x = 10;
            imagineDeTras.y = 10;
            var fundalLoader2:Loader = new Loader();    
            var fundalLoaderURL2:URLRequest = new URLRequest("butStartInactiv.png");
            fundalLoader2.load(fundalLoaderURL2);
            imagineDeTras.addChild(fundalLoader2);
            addChild(imagineDeTras);                


        imagineDeTras.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, dragObject);
            imagineDeTras.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopDragObject);    
            imagineDeTras.buttonMode = true;
            imagineDeTras.useHandCursor = true;
            imagineDeTras.mouseChildren = false;    

        function dragObject(evt:MouseEvent):void
            {
            evt.currentTarget.startDrag();
            trace("nume : " + evt.currentTarget.name)   
            }///// end drag object

        function stopDragObject(evt:MouseEvent):void
            {
            //trace("e.target.name " + e.target.name);
            trace("tinta atinsa este: " + evt.target.dropTarget.name);
            evt.target.stopDrag();  
            }//// end function stop drag    


    }/// end constructor

}// end class
}
```

When you drag and drop `imagineDeTras` over `target1`, the answer is "casuta1"
When I drag and drop `imagineDeTras` over `imagineDrag`, instead of "Tinta" the answer is `instance126`. Can somebody help me with this problem? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is a tiny mistake on your code!
On dragObject function you wrote :

`trace("nume : " + evt.**currentTarget**.name)`

And it's correct, But you forgot to use **currentTarget** instead of **target** on the stopDragObject!

```
trace("tinta atinsa este: " + evt.**target**.dropTarget.name);
```

You have to replace the **target** with **currentTarget** to make it trace the name of item that you add your listener to it instead of the name of it's child that mouse_up event triggered on.

Also you have to remove "dropTarge" after the curretlntTarget

You can see this if you have problem on understanding target and currentTarget: [AS3: Difference between target vs currentTarget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8517437/as3-difference-between-target-vs-currenttarget)

Comment: i try **currentTarget** before and after your answer i try it again, but the result is the same..... i still get _instance196_ instead of the name _Tinta_.... i guess it is something because in **imagineDeTras** i use a **loader** to load an image....... anyway thx for ur answer mr @MESepehr.....

Comment: Why did you add "dropTarget" parameter after "target"? remove it. it makes the name of dropTarget to trace.

Comment: i add "dropTarget" because i want it traced....... maybe i did not explain very well,,,,, but "dropTarget" is my problem..... he does not return the name that i wish when **imagineDeTras** is dropped on **imagineDrag**....  i want "dropTarget" to return the name _Tinta_ and not the name of an instance...... "dropTarget" work perfectly on **target1** but wrong on **imagineDrag**.......anyway thx for trying to explain.....

Comment: Oh, now I understood. the dropTarget parameter makes the last child of the dropped target to return. it could be even a Shape. so you may reach to your destination by calling droppedTarget.parent!
I solved a problem like that by writing a loop of .parent to get back to the element that i need.

Comment: see this : https://wildbunny.co.uk/blog/2011/07/07/mouseenabled-vs-droptarget-in-as3/

Comment: @MESepher thx very much for ur answer....but i had to do somenthing else and i didn't have time to try ur solution..... i will try it this weekend and i'll keep u in touch...... thx again.....