# What is the exact difference between currentTarget property and target property in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

What is the exact difference between `currentTarget` and `target` property in JavaScript events with an example and which property is used in which scenario?

Comment: Its important esp cause some browsers have different approaches, eg if you listen to a div copy event, in FF you will get a textNode instead of an element, but the listener will be at the div level.

Comment: there is a similar concept in as3 language , I have discussed it in both as3 and js and compared them in this post   https://stackoverflow.com/a/75975977/6863768

Answer (score 1003, accepted):

Events [bubble](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_bubbling_and_capture) by default. So the difference between the two is:

- `target` is the element that triggered the event (e.g., the user clicked on)
- `currentTarget` is the element that the event listener is attached to.

Comment: target = element that triggered event; 
currentTarget = element that listens to event.

Comment: @markmarijnissen You should definitely put your comment as an answer since it's more useful than the answer above and more voted also!

Comment: Can you please update your answer per [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10086427/what-is-the-exact-difference-between-currenttarget-property-and-target-property#comment39457506_10086501)

Comment: think of currentTarget as "specifiedTarget"

Comment: It's not always an element. e.g. `XMLHttpRequest`

Comment: @markmarijnissen, Elements fires an event, they do not listen to it. We just assign handler to execute it, when it occurs.
currentTarget is the one where event handler got attached.

Comment: @markmarijnissen Elements do **not** listen to events. It's the listener (provided by the Web-Api of the browser) that gets attached to the element and listens for events.

Comment: here a good explanation with a use case : https://thisthat.dev/current-target-vs-target/

Comment: I know that terminology matters, but I feel like it's ok to say that the element listens to the event. I could be wrong but to me the complaint about what is doing the listening sounds kind of like, "your car isn't powered by gasoline, it's powered by burning the gasoline", or "you're not driving your kids to school, you're driving a car that they are riding in to get them to school".

Answer (score 194):

`target` = element that triggered event.

`currentTarget` = element that has the event listener.

Comment: Elements fire an event, they do not listen to it. We just assign handler to execute it, when it occurs.
currentTarget is the one where event handler got attached.

Comment: @SamyakJain Then why is the function called `.addEventListener()` if it doesn't listen to an event?

Comment: @Samathingamajig Because you **add** an event-listener **to** an HTML-element. It's not the element that listens, rather it's a listener in the Web-Api that is provided by the browser.

Answer (score 77):

**Minimal runnable example**

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var resultElem = document.getElementById('result')
  document.getElementById('1').addEventListener(
    'click',
    function(event) {
      resultElem.innerHTML += ('<div>target: ' + event.target.id + '</div>')
      resultElem.innerHTML += ('<div>currentTarget: ' + event.currentTarget.id + '</div>')
    },
    false
  )
  document.getElementById('2').dispatchEvent(
          new Event('click', { bubbles:true }))
}
```

```html
<div id="1">1 click me
  <div id="2">2 click me as well</div>
</div>
<div id="result">
  <div>result:</div>
</div>
```

If you click on:

```
2 click me as well
```

then `1` listens to it, and appends to the result:

```
target: 2
currentTarget: 1
```

because in that case:

- `2` is the element that originated the event
- `1` is the element that listened to the event

If you click on:

```
1 click me
```

instead, the result is:

```
target: 1
currentTarget: 1
```

Tested on Chromium 71.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation with an example.

Answer (score 43):

For events whose [bubbles property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/bubbles) is `true`, they bubble.

Most events do bubble, except several, namely [focus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/focus_event), [blur](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/blur_event), [mouseenter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseenter_event), [mouseleave](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseleave_event), ...

If an event `evt` bubbles, the `evt.currentTarget` is changed to the **current target** in its bubbling path, while the `evt.target` keeps the same value as the original target which triggered the event.

[image: Event's target types]

It is worth noting that if your event handler (of an event that bubbles) is asynchronous and the handler uses `evt.currentTarget`. `currentTarget` should be cached locally because the event object is reused in the bubbling chain ([codepen](https://codepen.io/tranvansang/pen/rNMzBNq)).

```
const clickHandler = evt => {
  const {currentTarget} = evt // cache property locally
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('evt.currentTarget changed', evt.currentTarget !== currentTarget)
  }, 3000)
}
```

If you use React, from v17, react drops the [Event Pooling](https://reactjs.org/docs/legacy-event-pooling.html).

<strike>Therefore, the event object is refreshed in the handler and can be safe to use in asynchronous calls ([codepen](https://codepen.io/tranvansang/pen/JjRyPdQ?editors=0010)).</strike>

↑is not always true. `onClick` event's `currentTarget` is `undefined` after the event handler finishes. In conclusion, **always** cache the event's properties locally if you are going to use them after a synchronous call.

From [react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#overview)

> Note:
>
> As of v17, e.persist() doesn’t do anything because the SyntheticEvent
> is no longer pooled.

And many other things that are too long to be pasted in an answer, so I summarized and made [a blog post here](https://transang.me/everything-about-event-bubbling/).

Answer (score 36):

If this isn't sticking, try this:

**current** in `currentTarget` refers to the present. It's the most recent target that caught the event that bubbled up from elsewhere.

Comment: It is useful to look at this from the perspective of the bubbling phase. My initial guess was that `currentTarget` refers to the element that triggered the event, since `current` implies variability and it is the triggered object that can change between events.

Answer (score 14):

```html
<style>
  body * {
    margin: 10px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
  }
</style>

<form onclick="alert('form')">FORM
  <div onclick="alert('div')">DIV
    <p onclick="alert('p')">P</p>
  </div>
</form>
```

If  click on the P tag in above code then you will get three alert,and if you click on the div tag you will get two alert and a single alert on clicking the form tag.
And now see the following code,

```html
<style>
  body * {
    margin: 10px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
  }
</style>
<script>
function fun(event){
  alert(event.target+" "+event.currentTarget);
}

</script>

<form>FORM
  <div onclick="fun(event)">DIV
    <p>P</p>
  </div>
</form>
```

We just removed onclick from the P and form tag and now when we click we on P tag we get only one alert:

> [object HTMLParagraphElement] [object HTMLDivElement]

Here event.target is [object HTMLParagraphElement],and event.curentTarget is [object HTMLDivElement]:
So

> event.target is the node from which the event originated,
>   and
>   event.currentTarget, on the opposite, refers to the node on which current-event listener was attached.To know more [see bubbling](http://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing)

Here we clicked on P tag but we don't have listener on P but on its parent element div.

Comment: It is the a good example from my opinion. It clears my head

Comment: Thís should be a great example. I'm a nut but can fully understand.

Answer (score 10):

> `Event.currentTarget` is the **element to which the event handler has been
> attached**, as opposed to `Event.target`, which identifies the **element on
> which the event occurred and which may be its descendant**.

Source: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget)

`target` always refers to the element in front of `addEventListener` - it's the element on which the event originated.
`currentTarget` tells you - if this is an event that's bubbling - the element that currently has the event listener attached (which will fire the event handler if the event occurs).

See [this CodePen](https://codepen.io/x-x00102/pen/rNmqwwp) for an example. If you open up developer tools and click the square, you'll see that first the div is the target and the currentTarget, but the event bubbles up to the main element - then main element becomes the currentTarget, while the div is still the target. Note the event listener needs to be attached to both elements for the bubbling to occur.

Comment: The event listener needed to be attached to the parent element too for bubbling to work - I tweaked your CodePen to demonstrate this (answer edited) - see https://codepen.io/x-x00102/pen/rNmqwwp

Answer (score 4):

Here's a simple scenario to explain why it's needed. Let's say there are some messages that you show to the user with the format below, but you also want to give them the freedom to close them (unless you have a special mental disorder), so here are some message panes:

**[ A message will be in this pane [x] ]**

**[ A message will be in this pane [x] ]**

**[ A message will be in this pane [x] ]**

and when the user clicks on the **[x]** button on each, the whole corresponding pane must be removed.

Here's the HTML code for the pane:

```html
<div class="pane">
  A message will be here
  <span class="remove-button">[x]</span>
</div>
```

**Now where do you want to add the click event listener?** The user clicks on **[x]**, but you want to remove the pane, so:

- If you add the click event listener to the **[x]**, then you will have to find its parent on DOM and remove it... which is *possible* but ugly and "DOM dependent".
- And if you add the click event listener to the pane, clicking "everywhere on the pane" will remove it, and not just clicking on its **[x]** button.

So what can we do? We can use the "Bubbles Up" feature of the event system:

> "Events are raised and bubble up the DOM tree regardless of the existence of any event handlers."

**In our example, this means that even if we add the event handlers to the panes, we will be able to catch the events raised specifically by the [x] button clicks** (because events bubble up). So there *can be* difference between where an event is raised, and where we catch and handle it.

Where it's raised will be in the `event.target`, and where it's caught will be in the `event.currentTarget` (where we're *currently* handling it). So:

```js
let panes = document.getElementsByClassName("pane");
for(let pane of panes){
    pane.addEventListener('click', hndlr);
}
function hndlr(e){
    if(e.target.classList.contains('remove-button')){
        e.currentTarget.remove();
    }
}
```

(The credit of this example goes to the website [JavaScript.info](https://javascript.info/task/hide-message))

Answer (score 2):

**event.target** is the node from which the event originated, ie. wherever you place your event listener (on paragraph  or span), event.target refers to  node (where user clicked).

**event.currentTarget**, on the opposite, refers to the node on which current-event listener was attached. Ie. if we attached our event listener on paragraph node, then event.currentTarget refers to paragraph while event.target still refers to span.
Note: that if we also have an event listener on body, then for this event-listener, event.currentTarget refers to body (ie. event provided as input to event-listerners is updated each time event is bubbling one node up).

Comment: For anyone visiting this page, this answer is incorrect!! Check the accepted answer! This thing should be downvoted into oblivion. delegateTarget is the node which refers to where the event was attached.

Comment: @LittleTreeX yeah, it is the indexed answer from google

Answer (score -3):

An experiment:

```js
document.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  console.log(e.target, e.currentTarget);
});
document.querySelector("p").click();
```

output:

```
<p></p>
#document
```

The `target` (`<p></p>`) seems to be the element clicked, while the `currentTarget` (`#document`) is the element that is listening for the click event.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).