# get the width of the html element with this event

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

This meteor client code needs the width of the element for which the event happened but failed to get it. How can it be done? Thanks

```js
Template.swipe.events({
  'mouseup .swipe': function(e) {
    utility.mouseUp(e);
  }
});

utility = (function () {

  return {
    mouseUp: (event) => {
      console.log(event.currentTarget.width);
    }
}());
```

Comment: DOM nodes don't have a `width` property. Did you mean [offsetWidth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS_Object_Model/Determining_the_dimensions_of_elements)?

Comment: use .width() property.

Comment: @JanDvorak - offsetWidth wasn't the solution for me. However your link revealed the correct property I was searching for: scrollWidth. Just in case someone else has the same problem!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `event.currentTarget.offsetWidth` property instead of `width`.

Comment: "`target` = element that triggered event; `currentTarget` = element that listens to event" -  source: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10086427/5113030 . Related: https://thisthat.dev/current-target-vs-target