# Button with FontAwesome child makes the button target value undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I can't seem to figure how to solve this problem that if you click a react-bootstrap button with a fontawesome icon as a child, the `onclick` `target value` will be undefined.

But if you click just outside the text with the icon and still inside the button, the `onclick` handler will still work.

https://jsfiddle.net/utmcykcg/5/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue seems to be that `event.target` can change depending on where in the button you click. Using `event.currentTarget` instead should give you the results you're looking for.

```
onClick(e) {
  const btnValue = e.currentTarget.value
  alert(btnValue);
}
```

See also: [What is the exact difference between currentTarget property and target property in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10086427/what-is-the-exact-difference-between-currenttarget-property-and-target-property)

Comment: Thank you so much! it's now working as intended. I wasn't even aware that there is this currentTarget. TIL!