# Drag and Drop: Drop in non-valid dropzones

Tags: javascript, vue.js, drag-and-drop

I’m working on a drag and drop web application using Vue.JS and Vuex Store.
The functionality is implemented pretty much following the [mdn docs for “HTML Drag and Drop API”](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API).
So my Dropzone Component and Draggable Element Components work with event.preventDefault(). As I have nested Dropzones, I also use event.stopPropagation() on the Dropzones. Drag and drop with the designated compoents works fine.

[Nested dropzones illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J02ON.png)

My problem is:
When a user drops a Draggable Element outside of a Dropzone, the UI kind of breaks.
So what I’m looking for is a app-wide event Listener for drops in non-valid dropzone areas.

I tried it with a global “dragend” listener, but that doesn’t seem to work.
I also tried “mouseup”, but that seems to general.
Here’s what I tried:

```
new Vue({
    router,
    store,
    render: (h) => h(App),
    async created() {
        window.document.addEventListener('dragend', (e) => {
            console.log("global Dragend -------------- ");
        })

        window.document.addEventListener('mouseup', (e) => {
            console.log("global Mouseup -------------- ");
        })
    },
}).$mount('#app');
```

I'm hoping that somebody knows how to implement an app-wide EventListener that triggers after failed drops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution**

I found a solution that was quite simple in the end. I set up `ondrop` and `ondragover` Events on my main `Vue` component. If a user drops a draggable element outside of a valid dropzone, the `ondrop` Event fires, and I can handle my UI errors there.

```
    <template>
      <div
          @drop="wrongDrop"
          @dragover="wrongDragOver"
      >
      <!--Code-->
      </div>
    </template>
    
    
    <script>
    methods: {
        wrongDrop(event) {
          event.preventDefault();
          // drop outside of a valid dropzone
          // do things to handle errors
        },
        wrongDragOver(event) {
          event.preventDefault();
        },
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a 'no-drop' class to the elements that you don't want to be drop zones. And then when drop event received you can prevent drop

[How to prevent drop into a div element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38856098/how-to-prevent-drop-into-a-div-element)

Comment: Thank you @JackyLaMitaine, your input helped me to find the solution. I will update my question accordingly.