# issue with input button

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile

I have this search button that open a top bar on screen width less than 1080px but I have a problem on mobile with it... touching the button on mobile, the bar it doesn't appear here you have an example http://cosmoscreativeagency.com/alanic/index.html

this is the functionality:

- on screen > 1080px: the white line appears clicking on the search button
- on screen <= 1080px: the white top search bar appears clicking on the search button and the white line is set as display: none

snippet below:

```js
toggle();
window.onresize = function() {
    toggle();
}
function toggle() {
 var searchTop = document.getElementById('demo-1'); 
 if (window.innerWidth <= 1080) {
  
  document.getElementById('demo-2').addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
      
      document.getElementById('demo-1').style.top = '0px';
  }, true);

  document.getElementById('demo-3').addEventListener('blur', function(evt) {
            document.getElementById('demo-1').style.top = '-60px';
  }, true);

 } else if (window.innerWidth > 1080) {
  document.getElementById('demo-1').style.display = 'none';
 }

}
```

```css
body {
background-color: black;
}
#demo-1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  z-index: 300;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  top: -60px; }
#demo-1 input[type="search"] {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-right: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  color: #000000;
  border: none;
  opacity: 0.9;}
.subheader {
  position: absolute;
  top: 120px;
  width: 100%; }
#demo-2 {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 50px;
  float: right;
  z-index: 300; }
#demo-2 input[type="search"] {
  background: url(http://localhost/alanic/images/searchbutton.png) no-repeat 9px center;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  -webkit-appearance: textfield;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  width: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  transition: all 0.5s; }
#demo-2 input[type="search"]:hover {
  background-color: none; }
#demo-2 input[type="search"]:focus {
  width: 200px;
  padding-left: 40px;
  background-color: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: auto; }
@media screen and (max-width: 1080px) {
 #demo-2 input[type="search"]:focus {
    display: none; } }
 #demo-2 input:-moz-placeholder {
  color: transparent; }
 #demo-2 input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: transparent; }
 #demo-2 input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #fff; }
```

```html
<form id="demo-1">
  <input id="demo-3" type="search" name="buscar" placeholder="Search">
</form>   
<div class="subheader">
  <form id="demo-2">
    <input type="search" name="search" placeholder="Search">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: You know you can do an `<input type=search>`, right? But only if you like *HTML5* ...

Comment: Adding an event listener *inside* an event handler is generally a mistake. It's called "addEventListener" for a reason: it **adds** a listener, and does not affect any event handlers already registered.

Comment: @PHPglue `return false` from an event handler registered with `addEventListener()` won't stop the event. You must use `evt.preventDefault()` and, if a form is in use, a submit button should definitely be used.

Comment: Why do you get the 'target.id' and check if it's the 'demo-2'? you know it's. because the event listener is already on this element ..

Comment: You want the text from the input to show up on the second form? I wouldn't even use 2 forms. Be more specific as to what you want, please. If using a submit with `.addEventListener` you need to `evt.preventDefault()`. Better yet, don't use a submit.

Comment: no @PHPglue I never said that, I forgot to put the display none to the #demo-1 form, I just want to show #demo-1 when I make click on #demo-2 submit button and just on screen size less than 1080px

Comment: also I wanna hide #demo-1 when is onblur (when we make click outside the input search)

Comment: you re right @PhelipeRocha thanks... but still not working

Comment: @Pointy ... so what is the best practice or solution in this case

Comment: Question is unclear. Vote to close.

Comment: @PHPglue what is so difficult to understand??? "I just want to show #demo-1 when I make click on #demo-2 submit button and just on screen size less than 1080px" please check my answer

Comment: I think my deleted answer was the answer, despite the fact that I used a single form. I'm still wondering why you would need another form in the era of AJAX. Just control the `Elemnt.style.display = 'none'` and `Element.style.display = 'block'` depending on the `innerWidth` *(note window is implicit)*. Anyways... if there are this many comments and we can't figure out the answer, we are not the problem. Rephrase the question, please.

Comment: @PHPglue I know anything about AJAX

Comment: post again your question @PHPglue

Answer (score 1):

Actually when you click on the `input button` it returns the `target.id` as blank because it doesn't have `id` but when you click on form(just near to button) it will display proper id.
So what you can do is use `currentTarget.id` or `this.id`

See the difference between `target` and `currentTarget`: [What is the exact difference between currentTarget property and target property in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10086427/what-is-the-exact-difference-between-currenttarget-property-and-target-property)

Check the below snippet in full page.

```js
toggle();
window.onresize = function() {
    toggle();
}
function toggle() {
 var searchTop = document.getElementById('demo-1'); 
 if (window.innerWidth <= 1080) {
  
  document.getElementById('demo-2').addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
    var target = evt.target;
          console.log("target = "+evt.target.id)
          console.log("currentTarget ="+evt.currentTarget.id)
    if (this.id === 'demo-2') {
      document.getElementById('demo-1').style.display = 'inherit';
    }
  }, true);

 } else if (window.innerWidth > 1080) {
  document.getElementById('demo-1').style.display = 'none';
 }

}
```

```html
<form id="demo-1">
 <input type="search" name="buscar" placeholder="Search">
</form>
<form id="demo-2">
  <input type="submit" name="search" placeholder="Search">
</form>
```

Comment: it works just a part of your code thanks! please check my anwer is more what I was looking for I just have an issue, to your code just left the onblur and the issue I post in my answer, can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this works for you, but here it is:

```js
// external.js
//<![CDATA[
var pre = onload, doc, bod, htm, E; // change var pre if using technique on more that this page
onload = function(){
if(pre)pre(); // handle previous onload

doc = document; bod = doc.body; htm = doc.documentElement;
E = function(id){
  return doc.getElementById(id);
}
var out = E('output'), ipt = E('input');
function solution(){
  var iS = ipt.style, oS = out.style;
  if(innerWidth < 1081){
    iS.display = 'inline-block'; oS.display = 'block';
    out.innerHTML = ipt.value;
  }
  else{
    iS.display = oS.display = 'none';
  }
}
onresize = ipt.onblur = E('btn').onclick = solution;
doc.forms[0].onsubmit = function(){
  return false;
}

}
//]]>
```

```css
/* external.css */
#output,#input{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html;charset=utf-8' />
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='external.css' />
    <script type='text/javascript' src='external.js'></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <form method='post' action='#' name='form'>
    <input type='text' id='input' placeholder='search' />
    <input type='button' id='btn' value='Search' />
    <div id='output'></div>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not understanding the question, at all. Not clear what you want still.

Comment: your #input must by hidden on screen > 1080px and I want it to show it when you make click on your #btn on screen <= 1080px also I want to hide the #input when you make click outside the box

Comment: I hope this is what you're looking for?

Comment: almost done, just left to hide it onblur event and hide it on screen size > 1080 when you already click on it

Comment: please check my answer and look the functionality

Comment: You comments and answer contradict each other.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I was looking for, but there is still an issue... when I click on the submit button on screen less than 1080px it shows the search input like what I was looking for, that's ok, but when I resize the screen to more than 1080px (without refreshing the code) and I click on the submit button again it shows the input search even when the code says on window.innerWidth > 1080 to display none the input...

My question is, how do I return display:none on screen more than 1080px when I had the screen on less than that?

```js
toggle();
window.onresize = function() {
    toggle();
}
function toggle() {
 var searchTop = document.getElementById('demo-1'); 
 if (window.innerWidth <= 1080) {
  
  document.getElementById('demo-2').addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
      document.getElementById('demo-1').style.display = 'inherit';
  }, false);

  document.getElementById('demo-3').addEventListener('blur', function(evt) {
      
            document.getElementById('demo-1').style.display = 'none';
  }, false);

 } else if (window.innerWidth > 1080) {
  document.getElementById('demo-1').style.display = 'none';
 }

}
```

```css
#demo-1 { 
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form id="demo-1">
 <input id="demo-3" type="search" name="buscar" placeholder="Search">
</form>
<form id="demo-2">
  <input type="submit" name="search" placeholder="Search">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should insert the conditionals inside the click functions. I recommend you check [CSS media queries](https://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/) to assign certain styles depending on the screen size.

```js
  window.onresize = function() {
    if (window.innerWidth > 1080) {
      document.getElementById('demo-1').style.display = 'none';
    }
  }


  var searchTop = document.getElementById('demo-1');

  document.getElementById('demo-2').addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
    if (window.innerWidth <= 1080) {
      document.getElementById('demo-1').style.display = 'inherit';
    }
  }, false);

  document.getElementById('demo-3').addEventListener('blur', function(evt) {
    if (window.innerWidth <= 1080) {
      document.getElementById('demo-1').style.display = 'none';
    }
  }, false);
```

```css
#demo-1 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form id="demo-1">
  <input id="demo-3" type="search" name="buscar" placeholder="Search">
</form>
<form id="demo-2">
  <input type="submit" name="search" placeholder="Search">
</form>
```

Comment: Hi @Alvaro, Sorry please check the post again I modify it.... is a device compatibilty I have now

Comment: @KennyAmaro try to reduce your code to the problem you are having, and explain it with the exact problem in the question. "#example should show #otherexample on click", etc. because it is quite difficult to understand what is not working and how should it work

Comment: the code is more bigger is the css... the problem is I think there is something wrong in that code that doesn't make the button works on mobile, or there is something wrong on the javascript code.... I modify the post just to explain the funcionality and I reduce the best I could the css code