# How to know if an event is still bubbling?

Tags: javascript, html, event-bubbling

I have an SVG element with some nested elements. I have attached a `mouseout` handler to the SVG element. When I press the mouse in the middle of the SVG element and move it out of the SVG element, I get the following list of events:

```
down
out <path ...>
out <circle r="39.5">
out <circle r="40">
out <circle r="49.5">
out <svg ...>
up
```

This means the mouse has first left the path, than it has left the three concentric circles and finally it leaves the SVG element. I am just interested in the last event, which affects the element, who has the handler attached. The SVG element gets all the other events, because they bubble to the SVG element.

How can I know, if an event has been bubbled? How can I ignore those events, which do not affect the element, which has the handler attached?

Comment: [More information here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10086427/what-is-the-exact-difference-between-currenttarget-property-and-target-property)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be necessary to check, if `target` is the same as `currentTarget`. The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47694364/402322) to another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47694343/402322) claims, that this can be done with `===`. So I use now the following condition in my mouseout handler, to skip the situations, when the event is still bubbling:

```
svg.onmouseout = function (event) {
  if (event.target === event.currentTarget) {
    // Do what needs to be done after the mouse leaves the SVG element.
  }
};
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `event.target` property to see actually which elements was triggered the event.

```js
$('#myDiv').on('click', function(e) {
  console.log(e.target.id);
});
```

```css
#myDiv {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='myDiv'>
  <button id='myButton'>Click me</button>
</div>
```

Comment: How to compare elements?

Comment: You can give them ids for example and compare them