# Difference between event.target.value and event.currentTarget.value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was catching an input value in event handler like below:

```
import React from 'react';

export class Newsletter extends React.Component {
    handleClick(event) {
        let newsletterId = event.target.value;
        console.log(newsletterId);
    }

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            newsletter: this.props.newsletter,
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                 <button onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}
                                value={this.state.newsletter.pk}>
                         <span className="fa fa-arrow-right"></span> 
                 </button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

This was behaving strangely. Target value sometimes become `undefined`. Sometimes I was getting the correct `newsletterId` and sometimes I was getting `undefined`. See the screenshot below:

[image: target_value]

Then I changed `event.target.value` to `event.currentTarget.value`. Now it is working smoothly.

So, the question arose, What's the difference between `event.target.value` and `event.currentTarget.value` in this scenario?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

What was the cause of this strange behavior? Why I was getting the expected value sometimes?

This was happening because I was clicking on the `span` element which is inside the `button` element. While clicking on the `button` sometimes I was actually clicking on the `span` element. Those clicks are not bound to the `button` element rather it fires the click event on `span` element. And that was the reason of this strange behavior.

In short,

> `target`: whatever element somebody actually clicked on. It can vary,
> as this can be within an element that the event was bound to.
>
> `currentTarget`: is the element you actually bound the event to. This
> will never change.

**Reference:**

1. [Target value sometimes undefined](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/4745)
2. [event target vs event currenttarget](http://joequery.me/code/event-target-vs-event-currenttarget-30-seconds/)
3. [MDN Event.currentTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget)

Comment: Very nice the example, thank you.
Here some more references that could help someone else:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10086427/what-is-the-exact-difference-between-currenttarget-property-and-target-property
I think you could add your example to this other thread, it would probably help a lot of people.