# Updating aria-checked attribute of a button not working on Chrome but on Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, accessibility

I tried to updating aria-checked attribute of a toggle button using JS. It works perfectly fine on Firefox but can't toggle on Chrome.

When I log in JS, apparently the attribute got updated. But not on the actual UI when I viewed with Chrome devtool.

Here's [live on codepen](https://codepen.io/zarnihpyoe/pen/WyLvNa).

```
Please checkout codepen link.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`e.target` is selecting the span in Chrome, instead of the button on  which the event was binded, due to event propagation.

Use `e.currentTarget` instead of  `e.target`, it will select the button on which the event was originally bound and not any of its child elements.

```
// Rectangular switch
const rect = document.querySelector("#toggle-rect");
rect.addEventListener("click", e => {
  let checked = e.currentTarget.getAttribute("aria-checked") === "true";
  console.log(checked);
  e.currentTarget.setAttribute("aria-checked", String(!checked));
});

// Rounded switch
const round = document.querySelector("#toggle-round");
round.addEventListener("click", e => {
  let checked = e.currentTarget.getAttribute("aria-checked") === "true";
  console.log(checked);
  e.currentTarget.setAttribute("aria-checked", String(!checked));
});
```

```js
// Rectangular switch
const rect = document.querySelector("#toggle-rect");
rect.addEventListener("click", e => {
  let checked = e.currentTarget.getAttribute("aria-checked") === "true";
  console.log(checked);
  e.currentTarget.setAttribute("aria-checked", String(!checked));
});

// Rounded switch
const round = document.querySelector("#toggle-round");
round.addEventListener("click", e => {
  let checked = e.currentTarget.getAttribute("aria-checked") === "true";
  console.log(checked);
  e.currentTarget.setAttribute("aria-checked", String(!checked));
});
```

```css
/* reset button */

button {
  background: none;
  border: 0;
  color: inherit;
  padding: 0;
}


/* The switch - the box around the slider */

.switch {
  position: relative;
  /* display: inline-block; */
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}


/* The slider */

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  /* TODO: put disable color here */
  -webkit-transition: 0.4s;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: 0.4s;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

input:focus+.slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196f3;
}


/* Rounded sliders */

.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}


/* changing the background while toggling */

[role="switch"][aria-checked="true"] .slider {
  background-color: #2196f3;
}


/* toggling the handle */

[role="switch"][aria-checked="true"] .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}
```

```html
<!-- Rectangular switch -->
<button role="switch" aria-checked="false" class="switch" id="toggle-rect">
    <span class="slider"></span>
</button>

<!-- Rounded switch -->
<button role="switch" aria-checked="false" class="switch" id="toggle-round">
    <span class="slider round"></span>
</button>
```

Comment: It works like a charm. Thank you. One last question, so e.currentTarget() is a go to method over e.target()?

Comment: Read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10086427/what-is-the-exact-difference-between-currenttarget-property-and-target-property  It will help you understand the difference.