# how can i handle event capturing in react component?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Please read code first.

After css processing, it seems like memo application's single memo paper.

The goal of the component is to print a 1 when clicked(in real, the goal is to hadding redux store's state).

When i click outside of div component,  it works very well. ( it printed '1' )
but when i clicked inner div component(title, date,content), onClick event also proceed ( it printed '')
how can i prevent non-valued print?

### My code :

```
class container extends Component {

    handleState = (event) => {
        console.log(event.target.id)
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div onClick={handleState} id={value}>
                <div>title</div>
                <div>date</div>
                <div>content</div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

container.defaultprops = {
    value: 1
}
```

thanks.

Comment: check `if(event.target.id)` and then perform your operation??

Comment: yes. it works well(it printed '1'). the problems is when i clicked inner div part(title, date, content part), onclick event also proceed, and there's no value. so it printed ''.
I want to print a same value any part of the div.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use currentTarget:

```
handleState = (event) => {
  console.log(event.currentTarget.id)
}
```

About difference between target and currentTarget:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10086501/5709697

Comment: amazing! i did't know it existed :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `currentTarget` to check if it's the `target` since you bound the handler to the parent e.g.

```
 handleState = (event) = > {
     if (event.target == event.currentTarget) {
         console.log(event.target.id)
     }
 }
```