# React onClick button element as javascript node

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick

How can I grab the button element that fires the `onClick` event within the handler function? I don't wanna use `event.target` as it readily grabs the icon within the button element. Thanks.

Comment: pass on the reference of button with on click

Comment: `event.currentTarget` will return the element which has the event bound to it as opposed the element clicked. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_currenttarget.asp The issue is not specific to react. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10086427/what-is-the-exact-difference-between-currenttarget-property-and-target-property/10086501

Comment: Thanks, it works. Not the cleanest way to do it though.

Comment: This is how to access the node which has the event bound. Maybe make your question more specific if you are trying to solve a particular problem.