# Why does the js event in this code not bubble up?

Tags: javascript

I want to be able to click on div "three"  and it should bubble up to the other two?

```js
const divs = document.querySelectorAll('div');
divs.forEach(div => div.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  console.log(e.target.className);
}));
```

```html
<div class="one">
  <div class="two">
    <div class="three">
        Hello World
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works for me, what Browser are you using?

Comment: I am using chrome

Answer (score 2):

It does bubble up, you should get 3 log messages.

It logs `three` each time because `e.target` is the original element that the event is bubbling from. To get the current element in the propagation, use `e.currentTarget`. This code logs `three, two, one`.

See [What is the exact difference between currentTarget property and target property in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10086427/what-is-the-exact-difference-between-currenttarget-property-and-target-property?s=2|89.5218)

```js
const divs = document.querySelectorAll('div');
divs.forEach(div => div.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  console.log(e.currentTarget.className);
}));
```

```html
<div class="one">
  <div class="two">
    <div class="three">
        Hello World
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```