# React button mapped from an array value undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I mapped an array to buttons having the value to be the element of the array, but when I log the event.target.value to the console, I get undefined sometimes.

When I click each button, I get this in the console

```
0
1
2
3
undefined
undefined
undefined
6
7
undefined
9
```

Here's the code I have

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      selected: '',
      numbers: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
    }
  }

  handleClick = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    console.log(event.target.value);

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
          <Container>
            <Row>
              {this.state.numbers.map(i => {
                return (
                  <Col key={i.toString()}>
                    <ButtonToolbar>
                      <Button
                        value={i}
                        onClick={this.handleClick}
                      >
                        <h3>{i}</h3>
                      </Button>
                    </ButtonToolbar>
                  </Col>
                )
              })}
            </Row>
          </Container>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because sometimes you are clicking on the `Button` component, and sometimes on the nested `h3` element, and `event.target.value` of `h3` is undefined.

Best to pass the value within the onClick handler.

```
...
onClick={(event) => this.handleClick(event, i)}
...
```

```
handleClick = (event, i) => {
  console.log(i);
}
```

(You may want to omit the `event` value, if you have no use for it.)

**OR** if you want to stick to your current implementation, you can access the value via `event.currentTarget.value`.
[currentTarget vs target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10086427/what-is-the-exact-difference-between-currenttarget-property-and-target-property)

Comment: Oh this is just a sample code I wrote up, there're more codes in my actual code. Thanks a lot. This fixed the problem in my page