# Get attribute of clicked element using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6, dom-events

I want to get the "name" attribute of a div that was clicked and use it for another function using vanilla Javascript. I tried multiple solutions found on Stack Overflow, but nothing works. Can somebody help?

Here's what I tried (the version that made sense to me):

```js
let navLinks = document.querySelectorAll(".navbar .item");
navLinks.forEach(function(link) {
  link.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    let attr = e.target.getAttribute('name');
    console.log(attr); //logs null

    //openPage(".home");
  });
});
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <div class="container">
    <div name="home" class="item active">
      <div><img src="img/icons/home1.png"></div>
      <div>Home</div>
    </div>
    <div name="faq" class="item">
      <div><img src="img/icons/faq2.png"></div>
      <div>FAQ</div>
    </div>
    <div name="calc" class="item cta_calc">
      <div><img src="img/icons/dash1.png"></div>
    </div>
    <div name="about" class="item">
      <div><img src="img/icons/info3.png"></div>
      <div>About</div>
    </div>
    <div name="contact" class="item">
      <div><img src="img/icons/info2.png"></div>
      <div>Contact</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10086427/what-is-the-exact-difference-between-currenttarget-property-and-target-property/10086501

Comment: e.target is what was clicked, which seems to be the img tag.  You want e.currentTarget, which is the element that the listener is bound to.

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `target`use [**Event.currentTarget**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget):

> The `currentTarget` read-only property of the Event interface identifies the current target for the event, as the event traverses the DOM. It always refers to the element to which the event handler has been attached, as opposed to `Event.target`, which identifies the element on which the event occurred and which may be its descendant.

```
let attr = e.currentTarget.getAttribute('name');
```

```js
let navLinks = document.querySelectorAll(".navbar .item");        
navLinks.forEach(function(link){
  link.addEventListener("click",function(e){
    let attr = e.currentTarget.getAttribute('name');
    console.log(attr); //logs null

    //openPage(".home");
  });
});
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
    <div class="container">
        <div name="home" class="item active">
            <div><img src="img/icons/home1.png"></div>
            <div>Home</div>
        </div>
        <div name="faq" class="item">
            <div><img src="img/icons/faq2.png"></div>
            <div>FAQ</div>
        </div> 
        <div name="calc" class="item cta_calc">
            <div><img src="img/icons/dash1.png"></div>
        </div> 
        <div name="about" class="item">
            <div><img src="img/icons/info3.png"></div>
            <div>About</div>
        </div> 
        <div name="contact" class="item">
            <div><img src="img/icons/info2.png"></div>
            <div>Contact</div>
        </div>
    </div>       
</nav>
```

**OR:** You can simply use [**`this`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) keyword:

```
let attr = this.getAttribute('name');
```

```js
let navLinks = document.querySelectorAll(".navbar .item");        
navLinks.forEach(function(link){
  link.addEventListener("click",function(e){
    let attr = this.getAttribute('name');
    console.log(attr); //logs null

    //openPage(".home");
  });
});
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
    <div class="container">
        <div name="home" class="item active">
            <div><img src="img/icons/home1.png"></div>
            <div>Home</div>
        </div>
        <div name="faq" class="item">
            <div><img src="img/icons/faq2.png"></div>
            <div>FAQ</div>
        </div> 
        <div name="calc" class="item cta_calc">
            <div><img src="img/icons/dash1.png"></div>
        </div> 
        <div name="about" class="item">
            <div><img src="img/icons/info3.png"></div>
            <div>About</div>
        </div> 
        <div name="contact" class="item">
            <div><img src="img/icons/info2.png"></div>
            <div>Contact</div>
        </div>
    </div>       
</nav>
```

Comment: You can also use `this`.

Comment: Thank you very much!! This too worked...

Comment: @MohamedArkib, you are most welcome:)