# event.Target value is null for react form using hooks to handle change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hooks

I'm trying to study `react hooks`. this is a sign-up form that works well when using the classical class component with internal state and controlled forms. but when I try to use `react hooks` like this and type on the input **it just will not display what I'm typing**.

I have logged the event and have realized that the problem could be that the target value is null. Can somebody explain to me why this could be the case?

```
const SignUp = props => {
  const [displayName, setDisplayName] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [confirmPassword, setConfirmPassword] = useState("");

  const handleChange = e => {
    console.log(e);
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    switch (name) {
      case name === "displayName":
        setDisplayName(value);
      case name === "email":
        setEmail(value);
      case name === "password":
        setPassword(value);
      case name === "confirmPassword":
        setConfirmPassword(value);
    }
  };
  const handleSubmit = async e => {
    console.log(e);
    e.preventDefault();
    if (password !== confirmPassword) {
      alert("passwords do not match");
      return;
    }
    const { signUpStart } = props;
    signUpStart({ email, password, displayName });
  };

  return (
    <div className="sign-up-section">
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <FormInput
          type="text"
          name="displayName"
          handleChange={handleChange}
          value={displayName}
          label="display name"
        />
        <FormInput
          type="email"
          required
          name="email"
          value={email}
          handleChange={handleChange}
          label="email"
        />
        <FormInput
          type="password"
          name="password"
          handleChange={handleChange}
          value={password}
          label="password"
        />
        <FormInput
          type="psssword"
          name="confirmPassword"
          handleChange={handleChange}
          value={confirmPassword}
          label="comfirmPassword"
        />
        <Button type="submit" name="password" label="SIGN" />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};


const FormInput =({label,handleChange, ...otherProps})=>{
    return <div className='group'>
        <input {...otherProps} onChange={handleChange} className='form-input'/>
        {
            label?(<label className={`${otherProps.value.length? 'shrink':''} form-input-label` }>{label}</label>):null
        }
    </div>
}
```

Comment: What is `FormInput`? Is it from a library?

Comment: it is a custom input component. the signup component passes event handlers to it as props

Comment: Can you show it? `e.target` should be defined, but the custom input could be doing something to it.

Comment: i have edited the question to include the custom input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-form-hooks you want to setState for each change on the input field, so the onChange callback function will be called whenever there is a change to the input field.

coming to your callback function, the switch case should be like this:

```
    switch(cond){
    case 'cond1':
                 execute;
                 break;
    }
```

Comment: the switch statement is after i have logged the event and discovered that e.target is null. Do you know why the e.target is null but it is not when i switch to class component?

Comment: e.target is not null, open the link and proceed to type on any input tag and open the console to verify.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `e.currentTarget` instead?

```
const { name, value } = e.currentTarget;
```

That will ensure that you will get the element to which the event listener is attached.

See: [What is the exact difference between currentTarget property and target property in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10086427/what-is-the-exact-difference-between-currenttarget-property-and-target-property)

Comment: using the switch statement seemed to solve the problem but thanks for this resource.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see below, the problem isn't that `e.target` is null or undefined. The problem is actually in your switch statement.

You're blending syntax of `switch` and `if else` here `case name === "displayName":`. The switch automatically does the `name ==` part. In your case, all you need to do is put what `name` should be equal to - not the whole expression.

Change as shown below, with correct `case`'s and with `break`'s after the state update.

```js
const {useState, useEffect} = React;

const SignUp = props => {
  const [displayName, setDisplayName] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [confirmPassword, setConfirmPassword] = useState("");

  const handleChange = e => {
    console.log(e.target.name); // Logs correctly
    console.log(e.target.value); // Logs correctly
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    switch (name) {
      case "displayName":
        setDisplayName(value);
        break;
      case "email":
        setEmail(value);
        break;
      case "password":
        setPassword(value);
        break;
      case "confirmPassword":
        setConfirmPassword(value);
        break;
    }
  };
  
  const handleSubmit = e => {
    console.log(e);
    e.preventDefault();
    if (password !== confirmPassword) {
      alert("passwords do not match");
      return;
    }
    const { signUpStart } = props;
    //signUpStart({ email, password, displayName });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <FormInput
          type="text"
          name="displayName"
          handleChange={handleChange}
          value={displayName}
          label="display name"
        />
        <FormInput
          type="email"
          required
          name="email"
          value={email}
          handleChange={handleChange}
          label="email"
        />
        <FormInput
          type="password"
          name="password"
          handleChange={handleChange}
          value={password}
          label="password"
        />
        <FormInput
          type="psssword"
          name="confirmPassword"
          handleChange={handleChange}
          value={confirmPassword}
          label="comfirmPassword"
        />
        <button type="submit" name="password">Sign</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};


const FormInput = ({label,handleChange, ...otherProps}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <input 
        {...otherProps} 
        onChange={handleChange} 
        className='form-input'
      />
      {label ?
        <label>{label}</label>
      : null}
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<SignUp />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Wow. Thanks man. I was banging my head against the wall. I just couldn't fathom why it wasn't working.