# Error in event.target.name property. Sometime it reads the property other times it doesn't

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, event-handling, dom-events

I am getting an error when I click the button. it becomes weird because some it works and other times it doesn't.

```
import React from 'react';
class Profile extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state={
            posts:[],
        }
        this.increase = this.increase.bind(this);
    }
    increase(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var name = event.target.name;
        var post = name.split(':')[0];
        var applaused =name.split(':')[1];
        var k = name.split(':')[2];
        //some related code
    }
    render(){
        var posts=[];
                var k=-1;
                posts = this.state.posts.map((post)=>{
                   k++;
                   var namek=`${post._id}:${post.applaused}:${k}`
                   var applause=post.applaused=='applause'?<p>applause</p>:<p>applaused</p>
                return(
                <div key={post._id}>
                    <p>{post.post}</p>
                <button onClick={this.increase} name={namek}>{applause}</button>
                })
        return(
            <div>
                {posts}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Profile;
```

The error I am getting is-:

> Cannot read property split of undefined at line-: 13

Answer (score 0):

To avoid error "*Cannot read property split of undefined*" you need to check if your variable **name** is defined like this:

```js
if(name !== undefined) {
  // now you are sure that name is defined
}
```

== Side thoughts ==

Moreover, I'd rather split name once and then get every element from array:

```js
if(name !== undefined) {
  const nameSplitted = name.split(':');
  var post = nameSplitted[0];
  var applaused = nameSplitted[1];
  var k = nameSplitted[2];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The event target depends on the actual element you click. Sometimes this element seems to have no `name` attribute. So you cannot use the String#split method if `event.target.name` is `undefined`.

For debugging I would log the `element.target` and `name` value, before trying to split `name`, to see what element is the target and what name attribute it has.

```
    var name = event.target.name;
    console.log("Target is:", event.target, "and it's name is", name);
    var post = name.split(':')[0];
```

If you want to fix your error, you can check, if the element has no attribute `name`. There are multiple ways to do that, in this case...

- `if (!event.target.hasAttribute('name')) { // no name`
- `if (!('name' in event.target)) { // no name`
- `if (event.target.name === undefined) { // no name`
- `if (typeof event.target.name === 'undefined') { // no name`

Answer (score 0):

In the **increase** function you are using the **event.target**.

Because you have a button tag that contains a p tag it is possible that the **event.target** is sometime the p tag. It depends on where the user clicks in the button. The p tag has no **name** attribute so when the user clicks on the p tag inside the button the value is **undefined**.

You want to always get the button tag in the **increase** function. You can do that by using **event.currentTarget**. The **currentTarget** is always the tag on which the **onClick** attribute is set.

In conclusion: Use **event.currentTarget.name** instead of **event.target.name** so you will always get the value of the **name** attribute of the button tag.

```js
increase(event){
    var name = event.currentTarget.name;
}
```

More info about event.target vs event.currentTarget can be found in this StackOverflow answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37578174/1375229

A code snippet demonstrating the difference between event.target vs event.currentTarget:

```js
function increase(event) {
  alert(
    'event.target: ' + event.target.tagName + '\n' +
    'event.currentTarget: ' + event.currentTarget.tagName
  )
}
```

```css
button {
  background: #faa;
}

p {
  background: #aaf;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<button onClick="increase(event)">
  The button tag
  <p>The p tag</p>
</button>
```