# event.target.getAttribute("name") somtimes null?

Tags: null, undefined

I'm new to react and I wanted to make a button that when clicked opens up a sidedrawer that will close once you click on the backdrop that opens up as well. I have gotten this to work (sometimes) for some reason when I try to get the `event.target.getAttribute` it sometimes becomes null and sometimes not.

like this:

[image: consol.log output]

(consol.log output)

The button component that I click looks like this:

[image: Button component]

my backdrop looks like this:

[image: BackDrop component]

and this is the function that is called when I click looks like:

[image: handeClick]

(I have tried to only use `const {name} = event.target.name` but this only works for the button and I always get `name = undefined` when I click on the backdrop).
Can anyone help me understand why this is happening? Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10086427/what-is-the-exact-difference-between-currenttarget-property-and-target-property