# I want an event listener for each element inside a card

Tags: javascript

I have a card div in my application. When the user clicks this card element, it should fire a modal. However, I can't seem to attach the eventlistener for all elements inside the card element.

The card element looks like this:

```
<div class="card" data-id=${index}>
      <div class="card-img-container">
          <img class="card-img" src="${thumbnail}" alt="profile picture">
      </div>
      <div class="card-info-container">
          <h3 id="name" class="card-name cap">${firstname} ${lastname}</h3>
          <p class="card-text">${email}</p>
          <p class="card-text cap">${city}, ${state}</p>
      </div>
  </div>
```

How do I create an eventlistener that listen for all the elements inside the card element? Here's what my eventlistener looks like:

```
document.querySelector('.card').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
let dataId = parseInt(e.target.dataset.id);
let user = users[dataId];
showModal(user);

document.getElementById('modal-close-btn').addEventListener('click', () => {
  const modal = document.querySelector('.modal-container');
  document.body.removeChild(modal);
});
```

});

Comment: You shouldn't have to add a click handler to every element in the card.  Click events bubble/propagate.  It should be enough to put a click event handler on the card.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason to add an event listener for every element in the card. Instead bind an event listener to the `.card` element. Then use `event.currentTarget` to get your element.

Remember, [`target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) is the element you clicked and [`currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) is the current element in the bubbling process (the element that the event is bound to).

In your example `e.target.dataset.id` will most likely return `undefined` because you click on an element inside the `.card` div. `parseInt(undefined)` will return `NaN` and `users[NaN]` will most likely also return `undefined`. This means most of the time you will be calling `showModal(undefined)` unless you click on the card padding (if there is any).

Using `currentTarget` should resolve the issue.

```js
document.querySelector(".card").addEventListener("click", event => {
  console.log("target:", event.target);
  console.log("currentTarget:", event.currentTarget);
  // this is how you get your ".card" element ^
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="card" data-id=${index}>
    <div class="card-img-container">
        <img class="card-img" src="${thumbnail}" alt="profile picture">
    </div>
    <div class="card-info-container">
        <h3 id="name" class="card-name cap">${firstname} ${lastname}</h3>
        <p class="card-text">${email}</p>
        <p class="card-text cap">${city}, ${state}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That helped solve the problem. I guess I don't quite get the difference between e.target / e.currentTarget. Although a bit clearer now, thanks!

Comment: @FredrikJohansson Check out the [`target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) and [`currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) documentation for a better explanation. If you are new to events in general I recommend checking out the [MDN Introduction to events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events) guide.

Comment: There is also a separate SO question that about this: [What is the exact difference between currentTarget property and target property in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10086427/3982562)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are on track already - though your question is not very clear.
You do not need to bind every element to a listener  only capture the parent (in this case ".card") and determine which element was clicked just like you have done.

`document.querySelector(".card").addEventlistener("click", function(el){ el.target; //was clicked });`

If you really want to bind all child element in the card (not recommended), then
`document.querySelector(".card *").addEventListener("click", function(){ });`

If this is not what you need then maybe I do not understand the question

Answer (score 0):

IF you need to set the event listener to several elements with the same class, you could use a `for` loop to loop though each element.. Attached is your code with a for loop around it.

```js
//Create a for loop and loop through all elements that coorespond with (document.querySelectorAll('.card'))

    //Sidenote: querySelectorAll() returns an array of all matching elements, so you can simply add an event listsner to each element in that array by it's index or by adding "[i]" 
    for(let i =0; i < document.querySelectorAll('.card').length; i++){

        document.querySelectorAll('.card')[i].addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        let dataId = parseInt(e.target.dataset.id);
        let user = users[dataId];
        showModal(user);

            document.getElementById('modal-close-btn').addEventListener('click', () => {
              const modal = document.querySelector('.modal-container');
              document.body.removeChild(modal);
            });
        });
    }


    //This should attach your "click" event listener to any elements with the class of "card"
```

This sets the event listener to all "cards" but you can apply the same method/for loop for any element. Hope this helps