# JavaScript Accordion not working when i click on accordion heading text or chevron icon

Tags: javascript, dom-events, accordion

I have built an accordion which I can add dynamically from an input and everything works fine except when I click on accordion heading text it doesn't work and also when I click on the chevron icon on the right side I get an error!! I am not sure why this happening. if I click on an empty space area it just works fine without any error. you can check the demo & code here on codepen -> https://codepen.io/tauhidul-islam/pen/eYZBzLY
Also here is some screenshot so you can understand. please let me understand what's happening and why. Thank you.

```js
const addForm = document.querySelector(".add");
const list = document.querySelector(".section-list");

// Template Generator Function
const generateTemplate = (section) => {
  let html = `
     <div class="accordion">
        <span>${section}</span>
        <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
     </div>
     <div class="panel">
       <span>Hey there you did it! :-)</span>
     </div>
    `;
  list.innerHTML += html;

  // accordion Selector
  const accordion = document.querySelectorAll(".accordion");

  // Show/Hide accordion Content on Click
  for (i = 0; i < accordion.length; i++) {
    accordion[i].addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      let panel = e.target.nextElementSibling;

      if (panel.classList.contains("panel")) {
        panel.classList.toggle("active");
      }
    });
  }
};

// Add Section
addForm.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const section = addForm.add.value.trim();
  if (section.length) {
    generateTemplate(section);
    addForm.reset();
  }
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 960px;
  margin: auto;
}

.add-input {
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #dadada;
}

.add-btn {
  background: white;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #dadada;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Accordian Panel */

.accordion {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background: #03a9f4;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 0px #dadada;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.panel {
  display: none;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 15px;
}

.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <!-- Add Section -->
    <form class="add">
      <input type="text" name="add" class="add-input">
      <button type="submit" class="add-btn">Add Section</button>
    </form>

    <!-- Section List -->
    <div class="section-list"></div>
</div>
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The error only pops up when you click on a child element? If so, this is happening because when you click on a child element, it is looking for the child's sibling, not the sibling to its parent element. Have you tried event.currentTarget.nextElementSibling instead of event.target.nextElementSibling? Here's an explainer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10086427/what-is-the-exact-difference-between-currenttarget-property-and-target-property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are using `e.target` in the `click` event of the generated `div`, that will reference the template `span` when you click on the text and the `div` when you click on the blue bar, so `.nextElementSibling` won't always point to the same element. Instead, you want to always be calling `.nextElementSibling` on the `div`. This can be accomplished by using `this.nextElementSibling`, however because you are also using an arrow function, `this` binding won't correctly reference the element that received the event (the `div`), so if you change to using an anonymous function and `this`, it works.

```js
const addForm = document.querySelector(".add");
const list = document.querySelector(".section-list");

// Template Generator Function
const generateTemplate = (section) => {
  let html = `
     <div class="accordion">
        <span>${section}</span>
        <i class="fa fa-chevron-down">^</i>
     </div>
     <div class="panel">
       <span>Hey there you did it! :-)</span>
     </div>
    `;
  list.innerHTML += html;

  // accordion Selector
  const accordion = document.querySelectorAll(".accordion");

  // Show/Hide accordion Content on Click
  for (i = 0; i < accordion.length; i++) {
    // Use an  anonymous function for the event listener so that 
    // "this" will bind to the element that recieved the event,
    // which is the `div` in this case.
    accordion[i].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      // We don't want to reference the element that triggered the event
      // because that might be the span or the div and you won't always get
      // the correct reference with .nextElementSibling. We always want to
      // start from the div, which recieves the event.
      let panel = this.nextElementSibling;
      if (panel.classList.contains("panel")) {
        panel.classList.toggle("active");
      }
    });
  }
};

// Add Section
addForm.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const section = addForm.add.value.trim();
  if (section.length) {
    generateTemplate(section);
    addForm.reset();
  }
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 960px;
  margin: auto;
}

.add-input {
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #dadada;
}

.add-btn {
  background: white;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #dadada;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Accordian Panel */

.accordion {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background: #03a9f4;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 0px #dadada;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.panel {
  display: none;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 15px;
}

.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <!-- Add Section -->
    <form class="add">
      <input type="text" name="add" class="add-input">
      <button type="submit" class="add-btn">Add Section</button>
    </form>

    <!-- Section List -->
    <div class="section-list"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without the loop for assigning the click handlers:

```js
const addForm = document.querySelector(".add");
const list = document.querySelector(".section-list");
const expand = (element) => {
  let panel = element.nextElementSibling;
  if (panel.classList.contains("panel")) {
    panel.classList.toggle("active");
  }
};


// Template Generator Function
const getAccordionItem = (section) => {
  let html = `
      <div class="accordion" onclick="expand(this)">
                <span>${section}</span>
                <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="panel">
                <span>Hey there you did it! :-)</span>
            </div>
    `;
  return html;
};

// Add Section
addForm.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const section = addForm.add.value.trim();
  if (section.length) {
      list.innerHTML += getAccordionItem(section);
    addForm.reset();
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 50px 0;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.container {
  width: 960px;
  margin: auto;
}

.add-input {
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #dadada;
}

.add-btn {
  background: white;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #dadada;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Accordian Panel */

.accordion {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background: #03a9f4;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 0px #dadada;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.panel {
  display: none;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 15px;
}

.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Dynamic Accordian</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.1/css/all.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <!-- Add Section -->
    <form class="add">
      <input type="text" name="add" class="add-input">
      <button type="submit" class="add-btn">Add Section</button>
    </form>

    <!-- Section List -->
    <div class="section-list"></div>
  </div>

  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```