# Problem Implementing Types for React Bootstrap ListGroup

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm implementing typescript in this React App. I am using react-bootstrap (types installed already). I have a list group with action items as below. To get the type for the click event on each item I have: `((event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLAnchorElement, MouseEvent>) => void)`
Not sure why it suggests this type because when I inspect the DOM I see buttons. Anyways below is the code for the listgroup.

```
<ListGroup id="riskQuestion-1" >
   <ListGroup.Item action onClick={(event:((event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLAnchorElement, MouseEvent>) => void) | undefined) => handleInput(setRiskAnswer1, 5, event)} >I was great!</ListGroup.Item>
   <ListGroup.Item action onClick={(event:((event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLAnchorElement, MouseEvent>) => void) | undefined) => handleInput(setRiskAnswer2, 3, event)}>I did good but can be better</ListGroup.Item>
</ListGroup>
```

Then my handleInput function is:

```
 const [riskAnswer1, setRiskAnswer1] = useState<number | null>(null);
 const [riskAnswer2, setRiskAnswer2] = useState<number | null>(null);

 interface InputParams {
    answerHandler:React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<number | null>>,
    value: number,
    event: ((event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLAnchorElement, MouseEvent>) => void) | undefined
  }

  function handleInput({answerHandler, value, event}:InputParams) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const parentEl = event.target.parentNode;
    const  parentId = parentEl.getAttribute("id");
    if (parentId) {
      const el = document.getElementById(parentId);
      if (el) {
        for (let i=0; i < el.children.length; i++) {
          if (el.children[i].classList.contains('selected')) {
            el.children[i].classList.remove('selected');
          }
        }
      }
    }
    
    event.target.classList.add("selected");
    answerHandler(value);
  }
```

I do have some event.target issues in this code but that might or might not be related to the main issue on hand. Main issue right now is that typescript is still showing an error on that `onClick`. When I hover over it below is what I see.

```
    (JSX attribute) onClick?: ((event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLAnchorElement, MouseEvent>) => void) | undefined
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: ReplaceProps<"a", BsPrefixProps<"a"> & ListGroupItemProps> | Readonly<ReplaceProps<"a", BsPrefixProps<"a"> & ListGroupItemProps>>): ListGroupItem<...>', gave the following error.
    Type '(event: ((event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLAnchorElement, MouseEvent>) => void) | undefined) => void' is not assignable to type '(event: MouseEvent<HTMLAnchorElement, MouseEvent>) => void'.
      Types of parameters 'event' and 'event' are incompatible.
        Type 'MouseEvent<HTMLAnchorElement, MouseEvent>' is not assignable to type '(event: MouseEvent<HTMLAnchorElement, MouseEvent>) => void'.
          Type 'MouseEvent<HTMLAnchorElement, MouseEvent>' provides no match for the signature '(event: MouseEvent<HTMLAnchorElement, MouseEvent>): void'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: ReplaceProps<"a", BsPrefixProps<"a"> & ListGroupItemProps>, context: any): ListGroupItem<"a">', gave the following error.
    Type '(event: ((event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLAnchorElement, MouseEvent>) => void) | undefined) => void' is not assignable to type '(event: MouseEvent<HTMLAnchorElement, MouseEvent>) => void'.ts(2769)
index.d.ts(1455, 9): The expected type comes from property 'onClick' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<ListGroupItem<"a">> & Readonly<ReplaceProps<"a", BsPrefixProps<"a"> & ListGroupItemProps>> & Readonly<...>'
index.d.ts(1455, 9): The expected type comes from property 'onClick' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<ListGroupItem<"a">> & Readonly<ReplaceProps<"a", BsPrefixProps<"a"> & ListGroupItemProps>> & Readonly<...>'
Peek Problem (Alt+F8)
No quick fixes available
```

So two questions:

1- What do I need to change

2- At first I had all the types for parameters inline within parenthesis but I moved them out to `interface InputParams` With this change now where I'm calling handleInput on the listgroup item, I'm seeing this error: `Expected 1 arguments, but got 3.ts(2554)` So seems like   `function handleInput({answerHandler, value, event}:InputParams) {` was not the right way to implement the types here? Don't worry all errors above were generated when I had all parameter types inline. So this is just something extra I wanted to ask.

Appreciate any guidance. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the current type signature for the `onClick` handler basically states that the parameter `event` is itself a function. To correct that, you'll just want to use the type of the event itself:

```
<ListGroup id="riskQuestion-1">
  <ListGroup.Item
    action
    onClick={(event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLAnchorElement, MouseEvent>) =>
      handleInput(setRiskAnswer1, 5, event)
    }
  >
    I was great!
  </ListGroup.Item>
  <ListGroup.Item
    action
    onClick={(event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLAnchorElement, MouseEvent>) =>
      handleInput(setRiskAnswer2, 3, event)
    }
  >
    I did good but can be better
  </ListGroup.Item>
</ListGroup>
```

In fact, since you're not trying to access properties only found on a `<a>` element, you can let the type default to the most broad type possible: `Element`, so you can just leave out the generics. The reason it's `HTMLAnchorElement` here is that a `ListGroup.Item` with an `action` renders a link - look at the generated HTML with your browser's developer tools' DOM inspector. You'll see an `<a>` there. Though it could be anything, and in fact you can specify it via the [`as` prop](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/list-group/#list-group-item-props).

```
<ListGroup id="riskQuestion-1">
  <ListGroup.Item
    action
    onClick={(event: React.MouseEvent) =>
      handleInput(setRiskAnswer1, 5, event)
    }
  >
    I was great!
  </ListGroup.Item>
  <ListGroup.Item
    action
    onClick={(event: React.MouseEvent) =>
      handleInput(setRiskAnswer2, 3, event)
    }
  >
    I did good but can be better
  </ListGroup.Item>
</ListGroup>
```

To address your second question, `function handleInput({answerHandler, value, event}:InputParams)` is a function that takes in *one* parameter which is an object with those properties. However, you're calling `handleInput` with three separate parameters, and as such it should be:

```
function handleInput(
  answerHandler: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<number | null>>,
  value: number,
  event: React.MouseEvent
)
```

Since you're not using [functional updates](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) here, you can get away with the following:

```
function handleInput(
  answerHandler: (answer: number | null) => void,
  value: number,
  event: React.MouseEvent
)
```

After fixing these issues, a few more appear in `handleInput`. The first one is that `event.target` may not be an element, and as such its type does not have `.parentNode`. In this case, it's better to use `.currentTarget`. See also [What is the exact difference between currentTarget property and target property in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10086427/996081).

After that modification, the function will be:

```
function handleInput(
  answerHandler: (answer: number | null) => void,
  value: number,
  event: React.MouseEvent
) {
  event.preventDefault();

  const parentEl = event.currentTarget.parentNode;
  const parentId = parentEl.getAttribute("id");
  if (parentId) {
    const el = document.getElementById(parentId);
    if (el) {
      for (let i = 0; i < el.children.length; i++) {
        if (el.children[i].classList.contains("selected")) {
          el.children[i].classList.remove("selected");
        }
      }
    }
  }

  event.currentTarget.classList.add("selected");
  answerHandler(value);
}
```

But alas, another error appears. This time because `parentNode` is of type `Node`. There's actually [many node types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType), with "element" being just one of them! But clearly, you're actually interested in the parent *element*, so by changing `parentNode` to `parentElement`, the function compiles:

```
function handleInput(
  answerHandler: (answer: number | null) => void,
  value: number,
  event: React.MouseEvent
) {
  event.preventDefault();

  const parentEl = event.currentTarget.parentElement;
  const parentId = parentEl.getAttribute("id");
  if (parentId) {
    const el = document.getElementById(parentId);
    if (el) {
      for (let i = 0; i < el.children.length; i++) {
        if (el.children[i].classList.contains("selected")) {
          el.children[i].classList.remove("selected");
        }
      }
    }
  }

  event.currentTarget.classList.add("selected");
  answerHandler(value);
}
```

As a finishing statement, I'll just say in general that this kind of direct DOM manipulation is pretty sketchy in the React world and can, and should, in most cases be implemented with React instead.

Comment: Thank you so much for providing an answer with such detailed explanation. All working now, thanks to you. You are a life saver!