# How to change css style of a collection of objects from event of another in React?

Tags: css, reactjs, attributes, event-handling, use-state

How do I change/add/remove style attributes in React? I am  used to query selector but I understand that isn't the best way due to state changes in React. In general how do i access style attributes in react and change them from another element event?

```
const elements = document.querySelectorAll(".option-item")

function changeBackground() {
    elements.style.background = "red"
  
  }


<div className="options-panel" onMouseOver={changeBackground}>
 <div className="option-item">1</div>
 <div className="option-item">2</div>
 <div className="option-item">3</div>
 <div className="option-item">4</div>
</div>
```

```
.options-panel{
  background-color:black;  //<<---when i hover over this corresponding element
}

.option-item{
  background-color:blue    //<<---all elements with this classname change to "red"//
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the reason is you pass [event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event#properties) to your function and try to define which property of event you want to call.
in your case, you need to get the target. so try like this :

```
const elements = document.querySelectorAll(".option-item")

function changeBackground(e) {
    e.target.style.background = "red"
}


<div className="options-panel" onMouseOver={changeBackground}>
 <div className="option-item">1</div>
 <div className="option-item">2</div>
 <div className="option-item">3</div>
 <div className="option-item">4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: that was an error actually on my part, in that situation the event would change the "options-panel" background if it was e. I actually want to keep the "options-panel" background the same color but change the other "option-items" to red when I fire the chanegbackground function. I updated it

Comment: so basically change the style of one or multiple elements, but from another (or parent) element.

Comment: for change parent you can try like this `e.currentTarget.parentElement` and for change child of element you can try `e.currentTarget.childNodes`.
by the way, you have this option to try them with `e.target.parentElement` and `e.target.childNodes`

Comment: if you want to know what is different between `e.target` its good to see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10086501/11544999)

Comment: thank you for trying to help although its not exactly what i was looking for since this project is in react. but i did find my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to support the previous answer and add that, you will probably need to add the onMouseLeave handler to reset the element's original background.

Answer (score 0):

```
//SET THE ATTRIBUTES VALUES YOU WANT IN STATE FIRST//
const [panelWidth, setPanelWidth] = useState("50px");
const [opacity, setOpacity] = useState(0);


//MY FUNCTIONS CHANGES OPACITY AND WIDTH VALUE//
function toggleStretch() {
    if (panelWidth === "50px") {
      setPanelWidth("300px");
      setOpacity(1);
    } else if (panelWidth === "300px") {
      setPanelWidth("50px");
      setOpacity(0);
    }
  }
```

```
//USE YOUR EVENT TO CALL A FUNCTION AND SET THE ATTRIBUTES BY PASSING STATE VALUE AS A STYLE PROP I CHOSE MOUSEOVER//

  <div
        className="options-panel"
        style={{ width: panelWidth }}
        onMouseOver={toggleStretch}
        onMouseLeave={toggleStretch}
      >
        <div className="options-item">
          <div>
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faHome}></FontAwesomeIcon>
          </div>
          <p style={{ opacity }}> Home</p>
        </div>
        <div className="options-item" onClick={toggleListHandler}>
          <div>{iconState ? <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faFolder} /> : <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faFolderOpen} />} </div>
          <p style={{ opacity }}> About</p>
        </div>
  </div>
```

For smooth transitions just add to your CSS file:

```
.options-panel {
 
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
}

.options-item {

  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}
```