# How does this function work? function (oFREvent)

Tags: javascript, function

I found a piece of code that changes the img on display once you get a file for a preview. I understand everything except for the meaning of oFREvent. I've searched it up and have seen other people using it but can't find what it does. Is there an effect that it has that differs from anything else that could be there?

```
        let oFReader = new FileReader();
        oFReader.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById("uploadImage").files[0]);

        oFReader.onload = function (oFREvent) {
            document.getElementById("uploadPreview").src = oFREvent.target.result;
        };
    };
```

This is the html for the function

```
<input type="text" name="imgName"><br>
<input id="uploadImage" type="file" name="newImg" onchange="PreviewImage();">
```

Comment: `oFREvent` is shorthand form `fileReaderEvent`. `FileReader` puts to callback function it when finished loading image as base64 string in this case. More [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL)

Comment: You probably shouldn't be using `readAsDataURL` to load an `img`: **it's sloooooww**. Instead use `URL.createObjectUrl` which is _much faster_:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL

Answer (score 0):

- In the JavaScript world, all event-handler functions should accept an `Event` object as the first function argument.

  - An event-handler function is a function specified as the *callback* for `addEventListener` and/or directly assigning to the (legacy) `onclick`-style function-properties (such as `onload`, `onunload`, `onclick`, etc).
  - Note that as of 2021, you should not use the `onclick`-style function-properties anymore, instead you should always prefer `addEventListener`).
- Each specific event in the DOM, such as a `<button>`'s `HTMLButtonElement`'s `click` event, has its own additional data (such as indicating which mouse button was clicked, or which keyboard key was pressed) which is passed via this `Event` object as subclass data

  - For example...

    - Mouse-related events, like `click`, `mousedown`, `mouseup`, etc  [put their additional data in an object of type `MouseEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent).
    - Keyboard-related events, like `keydown`, [put their data in `KeyboardEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent).
  - Note that *not all events* have their own `Event` subclass, and in many cases the `Event` object contains no additional information beyond the element that raised the event ([`target` and `currentTarget`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10086427/what-is-the-exact-difference-between-currenttarget-property-and-target-property#:%7E:text=Basically%2C%20events%20bubble%20by%20default,event%20listener%20is%20attached%20to.)).
- Similarly, `FileReader` has a `load` event which is fired when it loads the `File` object specified (this happens asynchronously, instead of all in `readAsDataURL`) because reading a file can take seconds or even minutes, and would otherwise block the script, which in-turn would block the web-page's UI thread.

  - `FileReader`'s [`load` event uses `ProgressEvent` for its `Event` subclass](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ProgressEvent). This is the same `Event` subclass used by `FileReader`'s `loadstart`, `loadend` and `progress` events, so you can use the same event-handling code for all events *if you're only updating a progress indicator*.
- In this case, the `onload` handler doesn't need to check the `ProgressEvent` object because the `onload` handler will only be invoked after the data is successfully fully loaded.

  - That said, there's at least 3 things wrong with the code you posted - I don't recommend using it in production at all.

---

I recommend using this code instead, fwiw:

- You don't need to use `FileReader` at all.
- Just pass the selected `File` (from `files[0]`) into `URL.createObjectURL` and use that URL  as the `.src` for your `<img />`.

```js
function onFileSelected() {
    
    const fileReader = new FileReader();
    const file       = document.getElementById("uploadImage").files[0];
    if( !file ) return;

    const objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL( file );
    document.getElementById("uploadPreview").src = objectUrl;

    if( window.lastObjectUrl ) {
        // This step is necessary to release the _previous_ objectURL (if any) to prevent leaking memory.
        URL.revokeObjectURL( window.lastObjectUrl );
    }

    window.lastObjectUrl = objectUrl;
}
```