# Property 'target' does not exist on type 'KeyboardEventHandler<HTMLInputElement>'

Tags: typescript, next.js

my vscode has an error in my input onKeyUp function when i try to access its input target and get its value.

```js
import React from 'react';

import styles from './styles.module.scss';

export function Step3() {
    function handleKeyUp(e: React.KeyboardEventHandler<HTMLInputElement>) {
        console.log(e.target.value);
    }

    return (
        <div className="d-flex justify-content-between">
            <input
                type="text"
                className="f-size-30 mt-3"
                name="name"
                placeholder="Type your name"
                onKeyUp={handleKeyUp}
            />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Which type my 'e' parameter should be?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider the name:

```
React.KeyboardEventHandler
```

A *handler* is generally the name given to a function that *handles* an event - it's a callback, not the event itself. The event is a *parameter* to the handler function, but the handler function is not the event parameter.

If you want to use the `React.KeyboardEventHandler` type, annotate the `handleKeyUp` function as it.

You also need to access the `currentTarget`, not the `target`.

```
export function Step3() {
    const handleKeyUp: React.KeyboardEventHandler<HTMLInputElement> = (e) => {
        console.log(e.currentTarget.value);
    }

    return (
        <div className="d-flex justify-content-between">
            <input
                type="text"
                className="f-size-30 mt-3"
                name="name"
                placeholder="Type your name"
                onKeyUp={handleKeyUp}
            />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Another option - one that I prefer when the handler is short - is to define it inline, so that the type can be determined automatically, and you don't have to go to the trouble of figuring out the proper name yourself:

```
export function Step3() {
    return (
        <div className="d-flex justify-content-between">
            <input
                type="text"
                className="f-size-30 mt-3"
                name="name"
                placeholder="Type your name"
                onKeyUp={(e) => console.log(e.currentTarget.value)}
            />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: do you know why this works and mine doesnt?

Comment: Because `KeyboardEventHandler` is the wrong type for the event - the *function* is the handler, the event is something different.

Comment: Excellent explanation @CertainPerformance but why should I use currentTarget instead of target?

Comment: @MartinGainzaKoulaksezian https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10086427/ - using `.currentTarget` means that TypeScript will know that the element is definitely an `<input>`. In contrast, if you use `.target`, TS won't be able to infer what element it is.