# EventListener added to parent div, but event.target becomes children element if clicked on

Tags: javascript, html, stimulusjs

I'm working with card shaped `div`s that I need to be clickable. I'm using JS (stimulusJS) to add an `EventListener` to them so when the user clicks on the card, the event listener is fired adding some CSS classes and populating some hidden fields with data that comes from the `div`s dataSet.

*card*

```
<div class="card d-flex flex-column data-selectable-target="selectable" data-pricing-model-value="flat_fee">
   <div class="self-end">
      <strong>
        <span class="mr-3" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<%= t(".tooltip") %>"><%= icon("exclamation-circle", classes: "h-4 w-4") %></span>
      </strong>
   </div>
   <h5><%= t(".title") %></h5>
   <p> <%= t(".description") %></p>
</div>
```

*JS controller*

```
import { Controller } from 'stimulus';

export default class extends Controller {
  static targets = ["selectable"]

  connect() {
    this.selectableTargets.forEach((element) => {
      element.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
        this.select(event.target);
      });
    })
  }

  select(element) {
    element.classList.add("selected")
    this.selectableTargets.forEach((target) => {
      if (target != element) {
        target.classList.remove("pricing-model-selected")
      }
    })
  }
}
```

**Problem:**
I'm using `event.target` expecting to get the parent `div` to which I added the `EventListener`.
Instead, if I click on the card's `h5` or `p` elements, they become the `event.target` messing up my implementation.
Is there anything that could be done to ensure that `event.target` always refers to the parent `div` to which the `EventListener` was added?

Comment: Use `event.currentTarget` to get the element that the listener was added to.

Comment: useful background reading: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10086427/what-is-the-exact-difference-between-currenttarget-property-and-target-property

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed. Add it as a response if you want.

Comment: ...Or use the stopPropagation() method: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation