# Typescript and React, different Types between Compile Time and Runtime for React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLInputElement>

Tags: reactjs, typescript, type-inference

TL;DR `Object.getPrototypeOf(e.target)` returns `HTMLInputElement` but the compiler says that the type is `EventTarget`

Long:
I have a simple input

```
      <input
        className="FilterInput"
        type="text"
        placeholder="Search for names..."
        onKeyUp={filter}
      />
```

and a function to manage the filter

```
    const filter = (e: React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(e.target)) // prints "HTMLInputElement"
        console.log((e.target as HTMLInputElement).value);
        // ... other code
    }
```

I'm trying to understand better the theory that is behind the type management of Typescript, however I don't understand why I have to typehint

`(e.target as HTMLInputElement).value`

in the second `console.log`.

If I don't do it, the compiler (compile time) says `Property 'value' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.`. So this means that at compile time the type of `e.target` is EventTarget.

However, at runtime tested with `Object.getPrototypeOf(e.target)`, the type is `HTMLInputElement` (which has the `value` property).

Why is this happening? Is it an error in my code, something related to React or some part of the theory of the type management in Typescript that I'm missing?

Moreover, shouldn't the indication of the generic type in the parameter declaration (e: React.KeyboardEvent<**HTMLInputElement**>) be enough?

Thanks

Comment: this is odd. i copied your filter method into my IDE and it did not complain after i removed your assertion (which i would consider intended, because of the reasons you describe). `e.target.value` throws no compile time error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer to this is actually more related to JS and DOM api's then it is to Typescript.

In short, what you really want is `event.currentTarget`, as it will be the actual element to which you attached the listener.

`event.target` can be any child element of your element. As it can be any element - it can't be typed safety, so it's typed as the lowest common denominator which is `EventTarget`. (but I will say I'm not sure why it's EventTarget and not `Element`)

For more information see this answer: [What is the exact difference between currentTarget property and target property in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10086427/1930482)