# How can I get this javascript function to work all of the time? (Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null)

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create two numerical inputs, each of which has their own custom '+' and '-' buttons. However, with my current code, it appears that the button functions only work some of the time. On the other occasions I get a `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'value') at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous>` error.

This is the HTML:

```
<div class="col">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="input-group mx-auto w-50">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <button class="btn btn-dark btn-sm minus" data-id="one"
                    type="button"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
            </div>
            <input type="number" id="one" 
                class="form-control form-control-sm text-center" value="0">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <button class="btn btn-dark btn-sm plus" data-id="one" type="button"><i
                        class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="input-group mx-auto w-50">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <button class="btn btn-dark btn-sm minus" data-id="two"
                    type="button"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
            </div>
            <input type="number" id="two"
                class="form-control form-control-sm text-center" value="0">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <button class="btn btn-dark btn-sm plus" data-id="two" type="button"><i
                        class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is the Javascript:

```
<script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    document.querySelectorAll('.minus').forEach(item => {
        item.addEventListener('click', event => {
            var input_id = event.target.getAttribute('data-id')
            console.log('Minus button clicked for input ' + input_id)
            var quantityInput = document.getElementById(input_id);
            var currentQuantity = parseInt(quantityInput.value);
            quantityInput.value = currentQuantity - 1
        })
    })
    document.querySelectorAll('.plus').forEach(item => {
        item.addEventListener('click', event => {

            var input_id = event.target.getAttribute('data-id')
            console.log('Plus button clicked for input ' + input_id)
            var quantityInput = document.getElementById(input_id);
            var currentQuantity = parseInt(quantityInput.value);
            quantityInput.value = currentQuantity + 1
        })
    })
})
```

Here is a sample of the output after clicking a few of the buttons:

[image: Sample output after clicking a few buttons]

Comment: If you have difficulty with type errors like this, consider using typescript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the exact difference between currentTarget property and target property in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10086427/what-is-the-exact-difference-between-currenttarget-property-and-target-property)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `event.target` may be the span inside the button, and therefore the code may not find the `data-id` attribute. Instead perhaps get the id without using `event.target`. Either use `item` or `event.currentTarget`.

Comment: Changing `event.target` to `event.currentTarget` worked for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

the click event happend on the `<i class="fa fa-minus"></i>`
you may use `Event.currentTarget` instead of `event.target`

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () =>
  {
  document.querySelectorAll('.minus').forEach(item =>
    {
    item.onclick = event => 
      {
      let
        input_id        = event.currentTarget.dataset.id
      , quantityInput   = document.getElementById(input_id)
      , currentQuantity = parseInt(quantityInput.value)
        ;
      console.log('Minus button clicked for input ' + input_id)
      quantityInput.value = currentQuantity - 1
      }
    })
  document.querySelectorAll('.plus').forEach(item =>
    {
    item.onclick = event => 
      {
      let
        input_id        = event.currentTarget.dataset.id
      , quantityInput   = document.getElementById(input_id)
      , currentQuantity = parseInt(quantityInput.value)
        ;
      console.log('Plus button clicked for input ' + input_id)
      quantityInput.value = currentQuantity + 1
      }
    })
  })
```

you can also simply do:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () =>
  {
  document
    .querySelectorAll('button.minus, button.plus')     
    .forEach( btn =>              // this is the button
    {
    btn.onclick = () =>         // no event argument needed
      {
      let
        input_Qte = document.getElementById( btn.dataset.id ) 
      , adding    = btn.classList.contains('plus') ? +1 : -1
        ;
      input_Qte.value = +input_Qte.value + adding   // use +input_Qte.value for integer conversion
      }
    })
  })
```