# onMouseEnter, get only section parent element

Tags: reactjs, onmouseover

I have this code in react 17.0.2, and I hope that when I hover over a section, the onMouseOver function that I pass to the component by props is executed.

This function just prints a console.log of the `e.target`.

When I hover over the section, I correctly see on console `<section id="amenities"... />`, but if I hover over any inner element of this section, the inner element is now consoled. Is there a way to ALWAYS get as `e.target` the parent `section` element instead of its inner elements?

```
<section
  className="resort-amenities"
  id="amenities"
  onMouseEnter={onMouseOver}
 >
  <h2 className="title">Amenities</h2>
  <div className="amenities-wrapper">
    {renderAmenities}
  </div>
</section>

cont onMouseOver = () => console.log(e.target)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the exact difference between currentTarget property and target property in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10086427/what-is-the-exact-difference-between-currenttarget-property-and-target-property)

Comment: thanks a lot, i was trying with target and relatedTarget. This comment solve my problem!