# What causes the glitch in getBoundingClientRect()?

Tags: javascript

I am struggling with a glitch caused by getBoundingClientRect() method. (see fiddle below). The goal is to make a bar following a cursor inside a container. The aforementioned method does not return valid results. I am a beginner in terms of JS - there is most probably an obvious reason behind this. I just can't find the anwswer.

https://jsfiddle.net/aveoL210/3/

```
var div_moving = document.getElementById('div_moving');
var parent_div = 'parent_div';

var movingDiv = {
  getCoords: function(e) {
    var rect = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();
    var y_pos = rect.top;
    console.log(y_pos);
    var y = e.pageY;
    y = y - y_pos;
    
    return (y);
  }
};

document.getElementById(parent_div).addEventListener('mousemove', function(e){
  result = movingDiv.getCoords(e);
  div_moving.style.top = result +'px';
  div_moving.style.display = "initial";
  
});
document.getElementById(parent_div).addEventListener('mouseleave', function(){
  div_moving.style.display = "none";
});
```

Comment: `a glitch` - please describe in more detail - what results are you seeing, what are you expecting instead

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], we wouldn't chase yor code through the internet.

Comment: `if(e.target.id !== 'parent_div') return;` as the first line of `getCoords: function(e) {` will fix that

Comment: You may also want to consider a solution using the [Intersection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API)

Comment: [What is the exact difference between currentTarget property and target property in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10086427/what-is-the-exact-difference-between-currenttarget-property-and-target-property)

Comment: @ths is attached fiddle not enough?

Comment: @pilotnik you should make a [mcve] on your question so we can test it out without moving away from SO.

Comment: @ths I see. Sorry - next time i’ll comply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `target` when moving the mouse down will alternate between the moving and parent div

while adding

```
if(e.target.id !== 'parent_div') return;
```

guard to the `getCoords` function fixes it a little, it's still glitchy

---

The better solution is to get the rect of the `parent_div`, regardless of the `e.target`

So .. try this

```js
var div_moving = document.getElementById('div_moving');
var parent_div = document.getElementById('parent_div')

var movingDiv = {
  getCoords: function(e) {
    var rect = parent_div.getBoundingClientRect();
    var y_pos = rect.top;
    var y = e.pageY;
    y = y - y_pos;

    return (y);
  }
};

parent_div.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
  result = movingDiv.getCoords(e);
  div_moving.style.top = result + 'px';
  div_moving.style.display = "initial";

});
parent_div.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
  div_moving.style.display = "none";
});
```

```css
#parent_div {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 1em auto;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  background: #f0f0f0;
}

#div_moving {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  margin: 0;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent_div">
  <div id="div_moving"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In `getCoords` you want to get `parent_div` all the time, so you have to use `e.currentTarget` instead of `e.target` otherwise, when `div_moving` is under the cursor `e.target` return `div_moving` and all calculation goes wrong, it will move to top and when you move your mouse again all wrong things repeat.

```
var div_moving = document.getElementById('div_moving');
var parent_div = 'parent_div';

var movingDiv = {
  getCoords: function(e) {
    console.log(e.target.id)
    var rect = e.currentTarget.getBoundingClientRect();
    var y_pos = rect.top;
    console.log(y_pos);
    var y = e.pageY;
    y = y - y_pos;
    
    return (y);
  }
};

document.getElementById(parent_div).addEventListener('mousemove', function(e){
  result = movingDiv.getCoords(e);
  div_moving.style.top = result +'px';
  div_moving.style.display = "initial";
  
});

document.getElementById(parent_div).addEventListener('mouseleave', function(){
  div_moving.style.display = "none";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The, what you called *"glitch"*, is actually what is expected to happen. Let me tell you why:

- The line `e.target.getBoundingClientRect()` is the source of the issue, precisely `e.target`.
- The, so called *glitch*, happens when the mouse is **on top** of the `blue line` element and at this point `e.target` no longer points to your `#parent_div` and instead `e.target` is `#div_moving`.

A quick fix would be by caching `#parent_div` in a variable so can use it later on, and on the `getCoords()` method we simply replace `e.target` by that new variable.

Here's a live demo:

```js
var parent_div = document.getElementById('parent_div');
var div_moving = document.getElementById('div_moving');

var movingDiv = {
  getCoords: function(e) {
    var rect = parent_div.getBoundingClientRect();
    var y_pos = rect.top;
    //console.log(y_pos);
    var y = e.pageY;
    y = y - y_pos;

    return (y);
  }
};

parent_div.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
  result = movingDiv.getCoords(e);
  div_moving.style.top = result + 'px';
  div_moving.style.display = "initial";

});
parent_div.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
  div_moving.style.display = "none";
});
```

```css
#parent_div {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 1em auto;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  background: #f0f0f0;
}

#div_moving {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  margin: 0;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent_div">
  <div id="div_moving"></div>
</div>
```

> **DISCLAIMAIR:** The above demo did not change a lot from the OP's original code which, by the way, can be hugely improved which is out of the scope of my answer.