# weird behavior of onclick - sometimes retrieves e.target.id and sometimes doesn't

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick

I'm experiencing a weird response by my onClick event handling.

I have a list of user boxes, which on click, I'm attempting to navigate the client to that specific user's page ( as if - `navigate("/farmershop/" + e.target.id)` )

I am debugging by console.logg my e.target.id, I only get the id (which I attempt to retrieve) printed when I click on certain areas in the user box. In case I don't press that specific part in the box (on the image), I get an empty string.

These are my functions responsible for stated task:

```
const handle_clicked_farmer = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.id);
      navigate("/farmershop/" + e.target.id);
  }

  const createTopFarmers = () => {
    return top_n_farmers.map((farmer) => ( // on click take to farmer's page.
      <Stack  sx={{marginTop: "3%", background: "green", marginLeft:"5%", width: "400px", borderRadius:"5px", boxShadow: "2px 3px 8px black"}}>
        
        <Box sx={{marginLeft:"2%", cursor: "pointer" }} onClick={handle_clicked_farmer} id={farmer.id}>
        <Typography  sx={{fontFamily: "Amatic SC", letterSpacing: "2px", fontSize: "50px", fontWeight: 700}}>{farmer.firstname}</Typography>
        <Typography  sx={{fontFamily: "Amatic SC", letterSpacing: "2px", fontSize: "50px", fontWeight: 700, marginTop: "-5%"}}>{farmer.lastname}</Typography>
        <img src={farmer.img} style={{width: "100px", borderRadius: "300px", border: "2px solid black"}}/>
        <Typography  sx={{fontFamily: "Amatic SC", letterSpacing: "2px", fontSize: "20px", fontWeight: 700, marginTop: "-5%"}}>location: {farmer.location}</Typography>
        </Box>
        
        <Box>
        {farmer.likes} likes
        </Box>
        <Box  sx={{backgroundColor: "green"}}>
          <Typography  sx={{fontFamily: "Amatic SC", fontSize: "25px"}}>{farmer.about}</Typography>

        </Box>
      </Stack>
    ));
  };
```

any ideas what might be the issue?

regards!

Comment: You can only have one element with the farmer id. You may have to use data attributes instead.

Comment: Instead of logging `e.target.id` you should log `e.target`.

Comment: because the target is the item you click on, it is not the item with the event listener that is attached. So if you click on a child, you get the child element. `e.target.closest('[id]').id` or `e.currentTarget.id`, but in the end, it is weird you are using React like this. This  is not a great React pattern.

Comment: Did you try the ```e.currentTarget``` ?

Comment: thanks! it works! what's the difference between target and currentTarget? ;[ I mean, the name quite implies it, I just don;'t understand the usage of target then.

Comment: @dani_l_n The difference is that "target" is the DOM element where your user really clicked. 'currentTarget' is the DOM element source of the event (where your onClick is declared)

Comment: @dani_l_n And, i forgot, you are welcome :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### First!

`e.target` is a DOM element, so `e.target.id` is the ID of the DOM element. Having a prop `id={id}` in a JSX component DO NOT guarantee you that the component will actually render a DOM element with the provided `id`

#### Second!

Speaking of DOM element, the `id` **must** be uniq on the page

So maybe for you, best would be to have something like:

```js
const handle_clicked_farmer = id => () => {
  navigate("/farmershop/" + id);
}
  const createTopFarmers = () => {
    return top_n_farmers.map((farmer) => ( // on click take to farmer's page.
      ...
      <Box onClick={handle_clicked_farmer(farmer.id)}>
       ...
```

Comment: Is currentTarget is not a DOM element?  Thanks for your answer!

Comment: events are DOM based, so currentTarget is also a DOM element. You can find the difference in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10086427/what-is-the-exact-difference-between-currenttarget-property-and-target-property

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things at play here, chief among which is likely that `Events` are [Synthetic](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html) with React.

You could a more sure-fire way of getting the farmer id by wrapping (also known as currying) your `onClick` function like so:

```js
const handle_clicked_farmer = (farmerId) => () => {
  navigate("/farmershop/" + farmerId);
}
```

With the `onClick` looking like this instead:

```js
<Box sx={{marginLeft:"2%", cursor: "pointer" }} onClick={handle_clicked_farmer(farmer.id)} id={farmer.id}>
```

At the same time you can do away with relying on the Synthetic Event