# How may I drag a line with multiple elements up or down in a list, without being able to change the order of elements within the line?

Tags: javascript, html, css

In brief, I want to take a single line with multiple buttons, input text fields, and text, and drag that line up and/or down in a list of similar lines, without being able to mess up the line itself.  I'd like to use HTML, CSS, and Javascript only, without importing libraries.

==

In HTML, I have a div that contains multiple buttons, input text fields, and text.  A number of these divs make an informal list.  All these divs are, in turn, inside another div.

I want to take one of these internal divs and drag it up or down so it inserts into a new place in the list.  (Not swapping with another informal-list element, but inserting into the list and pushing later elements down).

It is not important that the information be contained in divs; a table or whatever else is fine, so long as all the buttons/text fields/etc. are on the same line and can all be dragged around together.

==

I originally put each button, text field, etc. in a td, which was in turn inside a tr, which was inside a table, and did something similar to

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/Create-a-draggable-paragraph-in-HTML5

But when I dragged a line, the entire moved tr line would sometimes drop into another line's td element, which was not desired behavior.  I wanted the entire tr line to move above or below another tr, not to squeeze into a single cell element of another tr.

So I tried doing things using this approach

https://htmldom.dev/drag-and-drop-element-in-a-list/

Currently, if I drag a button, the button can be shifted left and right within the internal div element it is in.  This is not desired behavior; I want the elements in the internal div to stay in the same order, and to move the *entire* div, just as it is, up or down in the informal list of similar divs.

HTML below:

```js
let draggingEle;

// The current position of mouse relative to the dragging element
let x = 0;
let y = 0;

const mouseDownHandler = function(e) {
  draggingEle = e.target;

  // Calculate the mouse position
  const rect = draggingEle.getBoundingClientRect();
  x = e.pageX - rect.left;
  y = e.pageY - rect.top;

  // Attach the listeners to `document`
  document.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMoveHandler);
  document.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUpHandler);
};

const mouseMoveHandler = function(e) {
  // Set position for dragging element
  draggingEle.style.position = 'absolute';
  draggingEle.style.top = `${e.pageY - y}px`;
  draggingEle.style.left = `${e.pageX - x}px`;

  const draggingRect = draggingEle.getBoundingClientRect();

  if (!isDraggingStarted) {
    // Update the flag
    isDraggingStarted = true;

    // Let the placeholder take the height of dragging element
    // So the next element won't move up
    placeholder = document.createElement('div');
    placeholder.classList.add('placeholder');
    draggingEle.parentNode.insertBefore(
      placeholder,
      draggingEle.nextSibling
    );

    // Set the placeholder's height
    placeholder.style.height = `${draggingRect.height}px`;
  }

  // The current order:
  // prevEle
  // draggingEle
  // placeholder
  // nextEle
  const prevEle = draggingEle.previousElementSibling;
  const nextEle = placeholder.nextElementSibling;
  // User moves item to the top
  if (prevEle && isAbove(draggingEle, prevEle)) {
    // The current order    -> The new order
    // prevEle              -> placeholder
    // draggingEle          -> draggingEle
    // placeholder          -> prevEle
    swap(placeholder, draggingEle);
    swap(placeholder, prevEle);
    return;
  }
  // User moves the dragging element to the bottom
  if (nextEle && isAbove(nextEle, draggingEle)) {
    // The current order    -> The new order
    // draggingEle          -> nextEle
    // placeholder          -> placeholder
    // nextEle              -> draggingEle
    swap(nextEle, placeholder);
    swap(nextEle, draggingEle);
  }
};

const mouseUpHandler = function() {
  // Remove the position styles
  draggingEle.style.removeProperty('top');
  draggingEle.style.removeProperty('left');
  draggingEle.style.removeProperty('position');

  x = null;
  y = null;
  draggingEle = null;

  // Remove the handlers of `mousemove` and `mouseup`
  document.removeEventListener('mousemove', mouseMoveHandler);
  document.removeEventListener('mouseup', mouseUpHandler);

  // Remove the placeholder
  placeholder && placeholder.parentNode.removeChild(placeholder);
  // Reset the flag
  isDraggingStarted = false;
};

// Query the list element
const list = document.getElementById('list');

// Query all items
[].slice.call(list.querySelectorAll('.draggable')).forEach(function(item) {
  item.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDownHandler);
});

let placeholder;
let isDraggingStarted = false;

const isAbove = function(nodeA, nodeB) {
  // Get the bounding rectangle of nodes
  const rectA = nodeA.getBoundingClientRect();
  const rectB = nodeB.getBoundingClientRect();

  return rectA.top + rectA.height / 2 < rectB.top + rectB.height / 2;
};

const swap = function(nodeA, nodeB) {
  const parentA = nodeA.parentNode;
  const siblingA = nodeA.nextSibling === nodeB ? nodeA : nodeA.nextSibling;

  // Move `nodeA` to before the `nodeB`
  nodeB.parentNode.insertBefore(nodeA, nodeB);

  // Move `nodeB` to before the sibling of `nodeA`
  parentA.insertBefore(nodeB, siblingA);
};
```

```html
<div id="list">
  <div class="draggable">
    <button onclick="deleteRow(event)">&#10005;</button>
    <button onclick="splitRow(event)">+</button>
    <button class="flagButton" onclick="cycleFlag(event)">US</button>
    <button class="unitButton" draggable="false">Unit 1</button>
    <input type="text" size="2" value="0" /> Row command number Row destination number Loop count number
  </div>
  <div class="draggable">
    <button onclick="deleteRow(event)">&#10005;</button>
    <button onclick="splitRow(event)">+</button>
    <button class="flagButton" onclick="cycleFlag(event)">US</button>
    <button class="unitButton" draggable="false">Unit 2</button>
    <input type="text" size="2" value="0" /> Row command number Row destination number Loop count number
  </div>
</div>
```

What I tried:  To make an HTML element that contained multiple buttons and input text fields, and have that entire HTML element dragged up or down in a list of similar elements.

What I expected:  HTML element to be dragged up and down.

What actually resulted:  Approach 1:  Dragged HTML element inside a cell of another HTML element (instead of above it or below it).  Approach 2:  Dragged HTML sub-elements of the element left and right within the element, also not desired (want to move the entire element up or down).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `draggingEle = e.currentTarget;`

See [What is the difference between currentTarget and target property in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10086427/what-is-the-exact-difference-between-currenttarget-property-and-target-property)

```js
let draggingEle;

// The current position of mouse relative to the dragging element
let x = 0;
let y = 0;

const mouseDownHandler = function(e) {
  draggingEle = e.currentTarget;
  draggingEle.classList.add('dragging');

  // Calculate the mouse position
  const rect = draggingEle.getBoundingClientRect();
  x = e.pageX - rect.left;
  y = e.pageY - rect.top;

  // Attach the listeners to `document`
  document.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMoveHandler);
  document.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUpHandler);
};

const mouseMoveHandler = function(e) {
  // Set position for dragging element
  draggingEle.style.position = 'absolute';
  draggingEle.style.top = `${e.pageY - y}px`;
  draggingEle.style.left = `${e.pageX - x}px`;

  const draggingRect = draggingEle.getBoundingClientRect();

  if (!isDraggingStarted) {
    // Update the flag
    isDraggingStarted = true;

    // Let the placeholder take the height of dragging element
    // So the next element won't move up
    placeholder = document.createElement('div');
    placeholder.classList.add('placeholder');
    draggingEle.parentNode.insertBefore(
      placeholder,
      draggingEle.nextSibling
    );

    // Set the placeholder's height
    placeholder.style.height = `${draggingRect.height}px`;
  }

  // The current order:
  // prevEle
  // draggingEle
  // placeholder
  // nextEle
  const prevEle = draggingEle.previousElementSibling;
  const nextEle = placeholder.nextElementSibling;
  // User moves item to the top
  if (prevEle && isAbove(draggingEle, prevEle)) {
    // The current order    -> The new order
    // prevEle              -> placeholder
    // draggingEle          -> draggingEle
    // placeholder          -> prevEle
    swap(placeholder, draggingEle);
    swap(placeholder, prevEle);
    return;
  }
  // User moves the dragging element to the bottom
  if (nextEle && isAbove(nextEle, draggingEle)) {
    // The current order    -> The new order
    // draggingEle          -> nextEle
    // placeholder          -> placeholder
    // nextEle              -> draggingEle
    swap(nextEle, placeholder);
    swap(nextEle, draggingEle);
  }
};

const mouseUpHandler = function() {
  // Remove the position styles
  draggingEle.style.removeProperty('top');
  draggingEle.style.removeProperty('left');
  draggingEle.style.removeProperty('position');
  draggingEle.classList.remove('dragging');

  x = null;
  y = null;
  draggingEle = null;

  // Remove the handlers of `mousemove` and `mouseup`
  document.removeEventListener('mousemove', mouseMoveHandler);
  document.removeEventListener('mouseup', mouseUpHandler);

  // Remove the placeholder
  placeholder && placeholder.parentNode.removeChild(placeholder);
  // Reset the flag
  isDraggingStarted = false;
};

// Query the list element
const list = document.getElementById('list');

// Query all items
[].slice.call(list.querySelectorAll('.draggable')).forEach(function(item) {
  item.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDownHandler);
});

let placeholder;
let isDraggingStarted = false;

const isAbove = function(nodeA, nodeB) {
  // Get the bounding rectangle of nodes
  const rectA = nodeA.getBoundingClientRect();
  const rectB = nodeB.getBoundingClientRect();

  return rectA.top + rectA.height / 2 < rectB.top + rectB.height / 2;
};

const swap = function(nodeA, nodeB) {
  const parentA = nodeA.parentNode;
  const siblingA = nodeA.nextSibling === nodeB ? nodeA : nodeA.nextSibling;

  // Move `nodeA` to before the `nodeB`
  nodeB.parentNode.insertBefore(nodeA, nodeB);

  // Move `nodeB` to before the sibling of `nodeA`
  parentA.insertBefore(nodeB, siblingA);
};
```

```css
.draggable {
  cursor: grab;
}

.dragging {
  cursor: grabbing;
}
```

```html
<div id="list">
  <div class="draggable">
    <button>&#10005;</button>
    <button>+</button>
    <button>US</button>
    <button draggable="false">Unit 1</button>
    <input type="text" size="2" value="0" /> Row command number Row destination number Loop count number
  </div>
  <div class="draggable">
    <button>&#10005;</button>
    <button>+</button>
    <button>US</button>
    <button draggable="false">Unit 2</button>
    <input type="text" size="2" value="0" /> Row command number Row destination number Loop count number
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Amazing.  The solution mentioned worked; I'll have to do some reading to understand *exactly* why, but now I know what to look for.

I'll upvote once I get 15 rep.

Comment: Check the linked question. There are some good answers there.