# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'innerHTML')

Tags: javascript, for-loop, typeerror, addeventlistener, innerhtml

i'm getting this error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'innerHTML')`

my code:

```
for (var i =0;i<7;i++){
    document.querySelectorAll("button")[i].addEventListener("click",handleClick);
}
function handleClick(i) {
    var name=document.querySelectorAll("button")[i].innerHTML;
    alert(name+" got clicked!");
}
```

i tried using `bind` but it was also giving the same error, also tried using anonymous function that also didn't work.

I am trying to customize the alert with each button name but this all is just not working.

I think it might be because of the loop that this error is coming but i can't understand why

Comment: What does `document.querySelectorAll("button")` return ?

Comment: `i` isn't being passed to `handleClick`. You're better off using `e.currentTarget` (where `e` is an argument that's passed to your `handleClick` function) instead of querying your DOM again for all buttons and selecting just the one you need.

Answer (score 1):

1. Cache your button elements first.
2. Add listeners to them.
3. The handler has an implicit "event" argument you can access. The event's [`target` property](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10086501/1377002) will allow you access to element that triggered the event (here the clicked button), and from that you can grab its text content.

```js
// Cache the button elements
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');

// Iterate over the buttons and add a listener
// to each one
buttons.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', handleClick);
});

// We're passing in the event to the handler
// (here called `e`). You can use find the element that triggered
// the event with its `target` property and, from there,
// log its text content
function handleClick(e) {
  console.log(`${e.target.textContent} was clicked`);
}
```

```html
<button type="text">Button 1</button>
<button type="text">Button 2</button>
<button type="text">Button 3</button>
<button type="text">Button 4</button>
```

Alternatively, if you didn't want to add listeners to all your buttons, add one to a parent element, and have that catch events from its child elements as they "bubble up" the DOM (a method known as [event delegation](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-event-delegation/)).

```js
// Cache the parent element
const buttons = document.querySelector('.buttons');

// Add a listener to it
buttons.addEventListener('click', handleClick);

// When the handler is called
function handleClick(e) {

  // Check that the element that was clicked is
  // a button, and then log its text content
  if (e.target.matches('button')) {
    console.log(`${e.target.textContent} was clicked`);
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="buttons">
  <button type="text">Button 1</button>
  <button type="text">Button 2</button>
  <button type="text">Button 3</button>
  <button type="text">Button 4</button>
</section>
```

Additional documentation

- [`matches`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches)
- [Template/string literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)
- [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get the alert according to the button name you can simply do this.......

```
<button type="button" onclick="getAlert(this)">This is button 1</button>
<button type="button" onclick="getAlert(this)">This is button 2</button>

function getAlert(e)
{
    let thisIsButtonName = e.textContent
    console.log(thisIsButtonName)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You forgot to pass the `i` argument

```
for (let i =0;i<7;i++){
    document.querySelectorAll("button")[i].addEventListener("click",() => handleClick(i));
}
function handleClick(i) {
    var name=document.querySelectorAll("button")[i].innerHTML;
    alert(name+" got clicked!");
}
```