# Trying to use AJAX to delete one item

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I created a list of games in HTML and implemented a JavaScript function with AJAX to allow users to delete a game when they click on the Trash Can icon.

However, it's important to note that I have added an attribute called gameid to each game, which stores the unique code for each game. When the Trash Can is clicked, it sends this gameid to the game-delete.php script, which then executes a query to delete the corresponding game. However, it appears that the "gameid" is being received as null in this process.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  var gameDelete = document.querySelectorAll(".delete-game");
  console.log(gameDelete);
  gameDelete.forEach(function (button) {
    button.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
      const gameId = e.target.getAttribute("data-game-id");
      if (confirm("Want delete this game?")) {
        console.log(gameId); //return null
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("POST", "game-delete.php", true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader(
          "Content-Type",
          "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        );
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
          if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
            console.log("Response:", xhr.responseText);
          }
        };
        xhr.send("gameid=" + gameId);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<tr>
  <td><img src="fotos/assassin.png" class="mini" /></td>
  <td>
    <a href="detalhes.php?cod=11">Assassins Creed III</a
    >[Estratégia]<br />Ubisoft
  </td>
  <td>
    <a href="game-new.php"><span class="material-icons">add_circle</span></a>
    <a href="game-edit.php?cod=11"><span class="material-icons">edit</span></a>
    <button class="delete-game" data-game-id="11">
      <span class="material-icons">delete</span>
    </button>
  </td>
</tr>
```

When I use`console.log(e.target)\`, it displays the values of gameid, and upon inspecting the HTML, I can confirm that gameid is present in the markup. However, it seems that the gameid is still being received as null during the AJAX request to game-delete.php.

Developer Tools: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLeWs.png)

Comment: add enough HTML to the question to help. Can't see how an attribute of an element could produce the output you've shown in the image. Also, have you considered using `data-*` attributes on your elements rather than making up attributes?

Comment: Please [edit] your question when providing more detail. Code does not belong in the comments

Comment: the point of using `data-*` is that instead of `e.target.getAttribute("data-game-id");` you can do `e.target.dataset.gameId` ...

Comment: by the way, in that `console.log(e.target)` there is no attribute with a name that has any similarity to `game-id` ... not that you've shown anyway

Comment: Use `e.currentTarget`. `e.target` is the span. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10086427/what-is-the-exact-difference-between-currenttarget-property-and-target-property

Comment: @JaromandaX You can't really tell, since the `dataset` property is outside of the screenshot.

Comment: I'd also add `type="button"` to the `<button>` to avoid any form related issues that might crop up

Comment: It's the 21st century. Time to learn `fetch()` instead of `XMLHttpRequest`.