# Javascript: detect whether the user has clicked a link leading to an external site

Tags: javascript, href

I'm trying to find a creative solution to this one. I know there are alot of scripts out there, many from stackoverflow itself, that can do a 'scan' of the web page through a body onload- but this isn't quite what I'm seeking.

I'm looking for a single script that can be included on the header of the page (via include, so its included on all pages) that detects whether the href the user clicked is external or local, and if it is local it would display a message.

I have a solution already which requires me to include an onClick handler on each href. The problem is this particular site literally has hundreds of hrefs.. I'm looking for a very clean solution that will save me time.

I have a few scripts I'm playing with, I'm just wondering if anyone is familiar with such a way that could easily do this.

I'd prefer Javascript and not Jquery.

Comment: Are these links on your page? Can you share what you have so far, even if it's just for perspective?

Comment: Why attach an event handler to each `<a>`?? Why not just attach to the document itself and check if the eventObject.target is an anchor element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than attaching individual event handlers, you should rely on the bubbling mechanism using a delegate

```
var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];

body.addEventListener('click', function(e){ 
    if(e.target.nodeName === "A"){
        var href = e.target.getAttribute('href'),
            selfhost = window.location.hostname;
        if(href.indexOf(selfhost) !== -1){
            // display message here
        }
    }
}, false);
```

Comment: What would be the trigger for this script to execute?

Comment: Presumably you would put that exact code in a script file and include it in the head of the file as you mentioned. You would need to wrap it in window.onload so that it wasn't trying to access DOM elements before they were available. When a user clicks something and the event bubbles up to the body tag, the handler is executed checking if it is a link, if it is a link it checks if the hostname differs from the link and executes the inner most portion `//display message here`

Comment: I'm having problems getting your method to work. I've defined the script you provided in the header and at the end I did a window.onload to call it.. 

But nothing is happening =( 

I'm doing something wrong I imagine?

Comment: -nods- it works on JSfiddle just fine, but nowhere on my site.

Comment: The error I get is: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'addEventListener' of null

Comment: I have included the desired id to be targeted in both the code and the HTML. In your HTML\JS this would be 'links'.

Comment: Without more specific info this is the best I got, if you want to send me your HTML I can provide a more concrete example.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$.on()` http://api.jquery.com/on/ and bind it to your document. So you only need to attach 1 handler to handle ALL your thousands of links. Eg.

```
var onClickLink = function(e) {
    // handle event here
};
$(document).on('click', 'a', onClickLink);
```

Comment: If you wanted a pure JavaScript version, then the idea is to attach the `click` event to the document. And when the event fires, you have to get the actual element `e.target` instead of `e.currentTarget` [Read more about e.target vs e.currentTarget](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5921413/difference-between-e-target-and-e-currenttarget). But jQuery makes this so easy, why resist? :)