# Jquery get the actual control that fired the event.

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a following html:-

```
<button type="button" class="btn-add">
  <i class="some-icon"></i>
</button>
```

which creates a nice fancy button with an icon

I bound an event on the button click:-

```
function (e) {
  console.log($(e.target));
}
```

now when i click on the center of the button the output of the above javascript is `<i>` element because of e.target. Is there any other way to get the actual control that fired this event, in this case the `<button>` ?

Comment: Please show us the code that installed the event handler.  `this` inside the event handler should be the object that the event was bound to.

Comment: $(this) inside the click event

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read this [Difference between target and currentTarget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5921413/difference-between-e-target-and-e-currenttarget)

Here is your solution:
[Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/blunderboy/a9Ene/)

```
$('.btn-add').click(function(e) {
    alert(e.currentTarget.tagName);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use either `this` or `e.currentTarget`

```
$('button').click(function(e){
    console.log(e.target);
    console.log(this);
    console.log(e.currentTarget);
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/UNrWE/)