# Event appears to only fire sometimes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js, jquery-events

### The Code

I set up a jsFiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/6vd5C/1/

The JavaScript code in question:

```
var global_loggedOnUser = "User1";

$(function(){
  var viewmodel = (function(){
    this.feedbacktype = ko.observable("None");
    this.currentPage = ko.observable(location.href);
    this.currentUsername = global_loggedOnUser;

this.updateFeedbackType = function(item, event)
    {
      var newText = $(event.target).children("span").text();
      feedbacktype(newText);
    };

    return{
      pageUserIsOn : currentPage,
      theUser : currentUsername,
      feedbackType: feedbacktype
    };
  })();

  ko.applyBindings(viewmodel);
});
```

### The Goal

Whenever someone clicks on the button of the submission, I'd like to see the "Current Type" bullet point update to indicate caption on the clicked button.

### The Problem

- Sometimes the text updates to the correct words; sometimes it updates but is a null value.
- I cannot find a pattern or rhyme/reason; sometimes after being blank, clicking another element and then clicking the element that previously returned null now returned the correct text.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: FYI, for others: After receiving Dimitar's answer below, I found this good answer elsewhere on SO describing the differences between target and currentTarget: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5921413/difference-between-e-target-and-e-currenttarget

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of using `$(event.target)` use `$(event.currentTarget)`.

I'd like to expand a bit and explain the difference, when you use `event.target` you're getting the element that dispatched the event (*the actual element* literally) - like in your case, if you click on the `<i></i>` element which is nested within the button element, it will return the `<i></i>` notice that if you return the code to `event.target` and you click on the edge of your button it will work as expected.

In the case of `event.currentTarget` you're getting the element you're binding your listener to (which in your case is the actual button).

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly it. Wasn't aware of the existence of currentTarget. Worked liked a charm.