# How to make onkeydown working on all document except one div

Tags: javascript, html

I have HTML5 app in which I use shortcut keys. In this app I have also chat. When I write in chat window then shortcut keys also fire up. How can I exclude shortcut keys in chat window?

This is how I use `onkeydown`:

```
 <body onkeydown="Gui.doKey(arguments[0] || window.event)">
```

`Gui`:

```
var Gui = { 
    doKey: function (event) { 
        var key = event.keyCode || event.charCode; 
        switch (key) { 
            case 83: //s 
                skip(); 
                break; 
            default: 
                console.log(key); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where does "Gui.doKey" come from?

Comment: In `Gui.doKey`, check if `event.currentTarget == <your_div>`. If so, abort.

Comment: var Gui = {
    doKey: function (event) {
        var key = event.keyCode || event.charCode;
        switch (key) {
            case 83: //s
                skip();
                break;
            default:
                console.log(key);
        }

Comment: @Derija93 I tried your suggestion but event.currentTarget is always body element

Comment: @BartekKosa try that with target instead of currentTarget. currentTarget maps to the element who owned the event listener. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_target.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var Gui = { 
    doKey: function (event) { 
        if(event.target == <your_div>) 
             return;
        var key = event.keyCode || event.charCode; 
        switch (key) { 
            case 83: //s 
                skip(); 
                break; 
            default: 
                console.log(key); 
        }
    }
}
```

See [Difference between e.target and e.currentTarget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5921413/difference-between-e-target-and-e-currenttarget)

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to the markup to determine, that keydowns need to be ignored for it. Make your Gui.doKey method check the source element. If it matches, return before doing anything else.

HTML:

```
<div class="ignore_keydown chat_window">...</div>
```

JS:

```
var Gui = {
    doKey : function (keyboardEvent) {
        // If the class contains the ignore selector, return immediately
        if (keyboardEvent.srcElement.className.indexOf('ignore_keydown') === -1) {
            return false;
        }
        // Original code...
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you try the jquery :not() selector to exclude the div, the div I presume your chat is in?
http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/

Comment: jQuery hasn't been tagged in this question.

Comment: @Kobbe can you give an example how to do this in this specific scenario?