# ActionScript 3 - Find out which MovieClip called the event listener?

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash, mouseevent

This is my ActionScript:

```
var containers = [
              option1Container,
              option2Container,
              option3Container,
              option4Container
             ];

for (var i = 0; i < containers.length; i ++) {
    containers[i].BlueBox.filters = [myShadowFilter]; 
   //BlueBox is an object inside the container. The above line adds a DropShadow to BlueBox

    containers[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, optioniContainerOver);
    //give each item in the array the same mouse over and mouse out listener

    containers[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, optioniContainerOut);
}

//create a color transform called optionOver
var optionOver:ColorTransform = new ColorTransform();
optionOver.color = 0xCC6600;


function optioniContainerOver(evt:Event):void {
containers[i].BlueBox.transform.colorTransform = optionOver; //this doesn't work.
}
```

Now, as you can see, what I'm trying to do with the function called optioniContainerOver is, that whenever a movieclip inside the containers array is hovered over, I want just that specific MovieClip to turn orange (0xCC6600). Is there a way for me to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to take a look at the `target` of the event:

```
function optioniContainerOver(evt:Event):void {
    evt.target.BlueBox.transform.colorTransform = optionOver;
}
```

Depending on the composition of the `displayObject` firing the event, you may need to use `currentTarget` instead.

From the [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/Event.html#currentTarget):

> The object that is actively processing the Event object with an event listener. For example, if a user clicks an OK button, the current target could be the node containing that button or one of its ancestors that has registered an event listener for that event.

Comment: Hm, when I do that, it says 'TypeError: Error #1010: a term is undefined and has no properties. at MainTimeline/optioniContainerOver()'

Comment: okay, instead of evt.target, I changed it to evt.currentTarget and it worked.. you can change your answer and i'll mark it as answered.. here is a good explanation as to why it didn't work with target but worked with currentTarget, for future reference and if anyone else has this same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5921413/difference-between-e-target-and-e-currenttarget