# what is the difference between target and current target in flash.events.event propagation?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, event-handling, flash-builder

what is the difference between target and current target in flash.events.event propagation ?
And on which phase of event these two properties are same ?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/5921413/612920

Comment: He really doesn't want to look at the AS3 docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `target` is the element where the event has occured.

The `currentTarget` is the element that has the event handler that is running right now.

When something happens, for example the user clicks on something, that causes an event for the element that was clicked. That is the target element. If there is an event handler for that event on that element, it will be called. If the element is a bubbling event, it will "bubble up" through the parent elements and run any event handlers on the way, unless the code in an event handler specifically stops it from bubbling further.

When there is an event handler on the element where the event happens, the `target` and `currentTarget` will be the same for that handler.