# JQuery Type-error e is undefined issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This code is giving me an error:

```
var openPrayer = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id   = $(e.currentTarget).data('id');
    var json = $.getJSON('/user/prayers/' + id);
    var temp = new t($('#prayerTemp').html());

    json.then(function(resp){
        var modal = temp.render(resp[0]);
        $('body').append(modal);
    });
}
$('.open-prayer').on('click', openPrayer);
```

This is the error:

```
TypeError: e is undefined
```

I don't know where I am going wrong, the code above loads a `JSON` response into a template I've set up below:

```
<script type="t/template" id="prayerTemp">
    <div class="prayer-modal">
        <img src="/img/icons/heart_infographic_prayer.jpg" class="hearts"/>
        <div class="prayer">
            <h1>@{{=name}}</h1>
            <p>@{{=body}}</p>
        </div>
        <span class="close-prayer">&times;</span>
    </div>
</script>
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

instead of

```
 var id = $(e.currentTarget).data('id');
```

use

```
 var id = $(e.target).data('id');
```

its working fine.

if want to know more difference between `e.currentTarget` and `e.target` see here :-

[Difference between e.target and e.currentTarget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5921413/difference-between-e-target-and-e-currenttarget)

Answer (score 1):

```
var id = e.currentTarget.id;
```

Works fine too. But if you need IE < 8 compatibility use jQuery solution or solution explained at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.currentTarget)