# jquery type error :"TypeError: colorval is undefined,"

Tags: javascript, jquery

[Here is console screenshort](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvVb7.png)

[Plunker Link Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/wTByIx5rSfTOFWI7y5sN?p=preview)

```
var color = '';
var xml = '';

function hexc(colorval) {
    var parts = $(colorval).match(/^rgb\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)\)$/);
    delete(parts[0]);
    for (var i = 1; i <= 3; ++i) {
        parts[i] = parseInt(parts[i]).toString(16);
        if (parts[i].length == 1) parts[i] = '0' + parts[i];
    }
    color = '#' + parts.join('');
}
$("#mcor tr").each(function() {
    // alert("1");
    xml += '<mcor_info>';
    var td_len = $("#mcor tr td").length;
    //  alert("2");
    for (var b = 0; b <= td_len; b++) {
        //  var index = $('th').eq(b).text();
        xml += '<mcor' + b + '>';
        var tx = $("#mcor tr ").find("td").eq(b).css('backgroundColor');
        hexc(tx);
        xml += color;
        xml += '</mcor' + b + '>';
    }
    xml += '</mcor_info>';
});
```

I am getting this error: `Type Error: colorval is undefined`. 
I found a couple of other examples, tried to solve my error but didn't succeed:

[JQuery Type-error e is undefined issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25618810/jquery-type-error-e-is-undefined-issue)

[Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function while using jQuery UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23232897/uncaught-typeerror-undefined-is-not-a-function-while-using-jquery-ui)

Where is my mistake?

Comment: You should fix your indentation.

Comment: which Identification?

Comment: It seems to execute fine.. You sure you included jQuery properly?

Comment: I made some adjustments to your Plunker (but I'm too lazy to make it an answer tonight) : https://plnkr.co/edit/p0YPuWFU38lljMUzxROE?p=preview

Comment: Hey Blex This Is working perfect . Thanks Man .

Answer (score 0):

can you upload the code in jsfiddle, please? I suspect that the problem could be on the line "var tx = $("#mcor tr ").find("td").eq(b).css('backgroundColor');"

probably it is not getting the result that you think

**UPDATE**

what happen if you use that:

```
var parts = colorval.match(/^rgb\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)\)$/);
```

**UPDATE #2**

you can check the code in the following link:

https://plnkr.co/edit/g3boR5yHO895fz76EIKg

like you can see if I pass a rgb directly to the function it is working fine, that mean that the problem is the "tx" object, that means that you need convert that to string

```
hexc(String(tx));
```

Comment: yes sure, I ll uplode But this line  work perfect . "var tx = $("#mcor tr ").find("td").eq(b).css('backgroundColor');"

Comment: I tried this way also but same it's throwing error.

Comment: Hey Ronald I included Plunker link

Comment: I can't see the code, but you can test that with 2 things:

Comment: sorry my bad please check this link    https://plnkr.co/edit/wTByIx5rSfTOFWI7y5sN?p=preview

Comment: I will take a look