# AS3 - "parent" of eventlistener

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Ex: 
The variable something is a random sprite

```
something.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickHandler);

function clickHandler(e:MouseEvent)
{
    //Now I want to remove the eventlistener from something
}
```

How can I do that in AS3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
something.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickHandler);
```

or if `something` is a local variable or you use this handler for multiple sprites:

```
e.currentTarget.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickHandler);
```

[docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/EventDispatcher.html#removeEventListener())

Comment: What is the difference between e.target and e.currentTarget?

Comment: Answer on this question is not so simple... It hard to me to explain this in this comment. I recommend you to read this article for better understanding "event flow" - http://www.actionscript.org/resources/articles/860/1/Understanding-the-AS3-Event-Flow/Page1.html. In two words: currentTarget will be always that object that you use with "addEventListener". But target maybe its parent or child.

Comment: I also found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5921413/difference-between-e-target-and-e-currenttarget

Comment: Yep, this is explanation is also right. More wide then mine, but much shorter then article that I linked before =)