# Finding ID and value of form on keyup/click

Tags: javascript

I have a form with several different types of input (checkboxes, text,number etc)I want to be able to find the ID of the current element of the form the user is clicking on/typing on and the value they are inputting.

I currently am using  surprisingly `undefined` for the value. I really have no idea where to start with this(I don't wish to use jQuery)

the HTML

```
<form id = "myForm" >           
        <input type="text" id="name"  name="name"  placeholder ="Name" />       

        <input type="email" id="mail"   name="email" placeholder ="Email" />

        <input type="number" id="phoneNumber" name ="phone" placeholder = "Phone Number" />

        <label for ="emailFormat">Email Signup Format:</label>
        <select name="newsletter" id = "plain">
            <option value = "Plain">Plain Text</option>
            <option value = "HTML">HTML</option>
        </select>

        <label for="pets">Cars owned:</label>
        <input type = "checkbox" id="mini" class = "ck" name ="mini">I have a mini.
        <input type = "checkbox" id="motorbike" class = "ck" name ="motorbike">I have a motorbike.
        <input type = "checkbox" id="thundercar" class = "ck" name ="thundercar">I have a thundercar.
        <input type = "checkbox" id="brum" class = "ck" name ="brum">I have a brum.
        <input type = "checkbox" id="roadrunner" class = "ck" name ="roadrunner">I have a roadrunner.

       <button type="submit" id ="button">SUBMIT</button>
</form>
```

the JavaScript

```
var form = document.getElementById("myForm");

form.addEventListener("keyup", store);
form.addEventListener("click",store);

function store() {
  console.log(this.id);
  console.log(this.value);
}
```

Comment: As you can see, you're getting `myForm` and `undefined` - this is because you're targetting the form itself with the `click` listener - `form.addEventListener("click",store);`- the `undefined` is because a form has no `keyup` - you'll have to set listeners for each form element to know where the user currently is

Comment: `document.activeElement` gives the DOM which has the current focus, extract its ID from it then. But it may not be as good as it sounds. One way is by adding "focus" event handler to all that you require and record the last focused field in a variable.

Answer (score 6):

When binding the event to the form, and relying on bubbling of events, `this` will be the form inside the event handler.

To get the element the event was triggered on, you'd use `event.target` instead

```
function store(event) {
    console.log(event.target.id);
    console.log(event.target.value);
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/1tv664gv/)

Comment: which should be ideally used `currentTarget` or `target`?

Comment: @Rajesh http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5921413/difference-between-e-target-and-e-currenttarget

Comment: @Rajesh `currentTarget` will be the same as `this`

Comment: `currentTarget` is the element the event handler has been attached to, in this case also the form element, as opposed to `event.target` which identifies the element on which the event occurred, which seems to be what the OP wants

Comment: I would use onkeypress instead of onkeyup as well.

Comment: I guess you haven't been paying your Google fees, if it won't let you do searches yourself.

Comment: That you very much, this allowed me to make my program.

Answer (score 1):

cross-browser solution:

```
function store(e) {
    var target = (e.target)? e.target : e.srcElement;
    console.log(target.id);
    console.log(target.value);
}
```