# Angular anchor tag clicked element ID not showing

Tags: angular

I'm trying to get the id of the clicked anchor element. Here's my HTML:

```
 <div class="list-group col-md-4" *ngFor="let book of bookbook">
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item" id={{book.id}} (click)="selectBook($event)">
        <img src="{{book.image}}" alt="#">
        <p><strong>Price: ${{book.price}} | {{book.id}}</strong></p>
        <p>{{book.summary}}</p>
      </a>
  </div>
```

Here's the click function:

```
  selectBook(event){
      console.log(event.target.id)
  }
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can pass book

```
(click)="selectBook(book)"
```

Comment: Now why didn't I think of that before haha. Thanks! Although I'd still like to know why getting the id via event object isn't working.

Comment: Adding a breakpoint inside `selectBook()`, you could inspect the event object. More from Angular docs: https://angular.io/guide/user-input#get-user-input-from-the-event-object

Comment: Passing $event passes the MouseEvent object (type 'click'), not the list object

Answer (score 3):

Please do not confuse `target` and `currentTarget`

`event.target` property contains a reference to the element the event happened on.

It is very important to understand that during the capturing and bubbling phases this target does not change: it always remains a reference to the element you clicked. It can be `img`, `p` or `a` in your case.

To know which HTML element is currently handling the event we should use **currentTarget**.

Now try

```
selectBook(event){
   console.log(event.currentTarget.id)
}
```

See also

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget
- [Difference between e.target and e.currentTarget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5921413/difference-between-e-target-and-e-currenttarget)