# Angular $event with multiple children return different target

Tags: javascript, angular

I have this html element on my application:

**.html**

```
<a (click)="onOpen($event)">
    <i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i> 
    <p>Profile</p>
</a>
```

**.ts**

```
onOpen(event):void {
    console.log( event.target );
}
```

When I click on the element I get different results for `event.target` inside the function `onOpen()` dependening on the position I click on.

For example, if I click ont he element where there is the `p` text, the target is going to be the `p` element instead of the `a` element.

Is there a way to make it always be the element that has the click function?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46987482/angular-anchor-tag-clicked-element-id-not-showing/46987777#46987777

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `event.currentTarget` to get the element the listener is bound to

Answer (score 1):

*event.currentTarget* is what you are looking for

```
onOpen(event:Event):void {
    console.log( event.currentTarget );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Angular` return the true target because you actually click the `p` not `a`.The `p` is contain `a` with one hundred percentage width to cover.

One way to solve it , use `$event.currentTarget` to got origin target.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass a string or object in the (click) and play around with that instead trying to manipulate the DOM

For example:

in the .html `onOpen($event, 'profile')` or `onOpen($event, menu.profile)`

in the .ts file

`public menu: = { profile: {name: 'Profile', url: '....', icon: 'sample.svg', isActive: true }, home: {...} }`

Are you trying to add an active class in the menu item or what exactly are you trying to achieve ?

EDIT:

`<a (click)="onOpen($event, menu.profile)" [class.active]="menu.profile.isActive === true">
    <i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i> 
    <p>Profile</p>
</a>`

Comment: This is for other things. I really need the dom element to do some calculations and change the style of others (parent child elements). If it was just for classes, I could use routerLinkActive to activate the element.