# jquery .on change doesn't trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The following code doesn't work for me although a similar one works (http://85.255.14.137). The CHANGE_ME text should get replaced by a a value on each change of the input field. How can I correct that?

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<html>
<head>

<script>
  $(document).on('change', '.input', (function(){
    var par = $(this);
    var val = $(this).val();

    par.find("span.value").hmtl(val));            
  });

</script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="col-sm-4">
  <div>
    <form id="A" name="do_something" method="POST" action="/do_something">
      <p>
        <input id="A" class="input" type="number" min="5" value="5" step="1" required />
      </p><p>
        <span class="value">CHANGE_ME</span>
      </p>
    </form>
  </div>   
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `hmtl(val)` typo.  You should have seen an error regarding this in your browser console.  And your event handler function has a random `(` in front of it

Comment: Your code is syntactically incorrect.

Comment: `par.find("span.value")` wat? `par` is an input, it can't contain a span.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: as [Taplar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1586174/taplar) said, your supplied code has an extra `)` after you call the `.html()` method. As [APAD1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2827407/apad1) said, you also shouldn't have two elements with the same ID, but that's not causing your issue.

Second: this problem is a great opportunity to think carefully about DOM structure. As it stands, you can't `find()` from `$(this)` because `$(this)` is the input element that fired the `change` event. The input has no children, so `.find()` will never return anything. Because your input is inside a paragraph tag and your target span is in a paragraph that is the sibling of that parent, you have to do some complicated traversals up the dom, over, and down, like so:

```js
$(document).on('change', '.input', function() {
  var par = $(this);
  var val = $(this).val();

  par.closest('p').siblings('p').find('span.value').text(val);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div>
      <form id="A" name="do_something" method="POST" action="/do_something">
        <p>
          <input id="B" class="input" type="number" min="5" value="5" step="1" required />
        </p>
        <p>
          <span class="value">CHANGE_ME</span>
        </p>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

We can avoid this problem if we approach our DOM structure more meaningfully, and think a bit differently about how we handle the change event.

First, let's use more semantic tags in our form. [Inputs need labels](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label); and also keep in mind that [the output element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/output) is a better tag for displaying content that comes out of using an input:

```html
<form id="A" name="do_something" method="POST" action="/do_something">
  <label for="B">Pick a number</label>
  <input id="B" class="input" type="number" min="5" value="5" step="1" required />
  <output for="B">CHANGE_ME</output>
</form>
```

With that structure, DOM traversal is a lot easier!

```js
$(document).on('change', 'form', function(e) {
  // the form whose input fired `change`
  const $self = $(e.currentTarget);
  const $output = $self.find('output');
  const val = $self.find('input').val();

  $output.text(val);
```

(Note that we [don't use `this`](http://fizzy.school/replace-jquery-this) to reference the form element. `this` can be unclear, and we have better ways of referencing the element jQuery is interacting with, like the `event.currentTarget` or the `event.target`. The two are [subtly different](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5921615/6798240)!)

And here's the snippet with these changes together, for the lazy: :)

```js
$(document).on('change', 'form', function(e) {
  // the form whose input fired `change`
  const $self = $(e.currentTarget);
  const $output = $self.find('output');
  const val = $self.find('input').val();

  $output.text(val);
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

output {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div>
      <form id="A" name="do_something" method="POST" action="/do_something">
        <label for="B">Pick a number</label>
        <input id="B" class="input" type="number" min="5" value="5" step="1" required />
        <output for="B">CHANGE_ME</output>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Woohoo! Thank you mate for not only the working example but also for the exhaustive explanation. You made my day, mate! Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome! Thanks for commenting - I saw a chance to explain myself a bit better.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with your code. For one thing you spelled `html` wrong, another issue is that you are looking for `span` with the class of `value` *within* the `input`, but it's not inside the input. You can write it like this instead:

```js
$('.input').change(function() {
  var val = $(this).val();

  $("span.value").html(val);            
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-4">
  <div>
    <form id="A" name="do_something" method="POST" action="/do_something">
      <p>
        <input id="A" class="input" type="number" min="5" value="5" step="1" required />
      </p><p>
        <span class="value">CHANGE_ME</span>
      </p>
    </form>
  </div>   
</div>
```

Another issue, unrelated to this problem, is that you have two elements with the `ID` of `A`, which is not valid. `ID`s must be unique.

Answer (score -1):

In addition to `hmtl` typo. You're traversing / searching for `span` with class `value` using `.find` method. Unfortunately that's not present there.

Instead of traversing, you can directly access the `span` with `$(".value").html(val);`