# Click on table cell targets child element

Tags: javascript, html, dom, onclicklistener, addeventlistener

I have a simple HTML table with ids in some cells:

```
<td id="x-11"><b>Is it a cell?</b> What a cell!</td>
```

Now I'd like to pass the ID to a JavaScript function triggered onclick:

```
const $tds = document.querySelectorAll('td[id]')
    for (let i = 0; i < $tds.length; i++)
        $tds[i].addEventListener('click', ev => console.log(ev.target.id))
```

It works as expected if I click an empty area or normal text within the cell. But if I hit the text inside the `<b>` element something strange happens: The browser says that the `<b>` element is the `ev.target` - although it has no listener whatsoever.

Can someone explain this behavior or offer a solution?

**Update:** As stated in the comments, [Difference between e.target and e.currentTarget](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5921413/2733244) provides the answer (for ActionScript, but that doesn't make a difference here) but the question is different.

Comment: `event` object always targets the element which had **caused** the event, **regardless of the fact** that the element has event listener or not. In your case, `<b>` is inside of the element which has event listener, so it becomes `event.target`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between e.target and e.currentTarget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5921413/difference-between-e-target-and-e-currenttarget)

Comment: change target to currentTarget

Comment: Thank you, you're right. Strangely, Web Inspector shows `currentTarget` as `null` in my browser but it works anyway. And the naming of `target`/`currentTarget` suggest it's rather the other way around ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `this` or `ev.currentTarget` that always refers to the DOM element the listener was attached to, instead, the `ev.target` will refer to the element that fired the event, in this case, the DOM element that was clicked :

```
$tds[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
   console.log(this.id)
});
//Or
$tds[i].addEventListener('click', ev => console.log(ev.currentTarget.id))
```

Comment: I like the solution with `this` but it won't work within an arrow function. It's `function(ev) {console.log(this.id)}`.