# Using an img tag, what is the type of an event fired by onError?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to load an image. In case the URL fails, onError I want to load a different image. The code works, but I'm using type "any" for the event. What is the correct type for the event?

```
function addDefaultSrc(ev: any) {
  ev.target.src =
    "default.png";
}

<img src={item.src} onError={addDefaultSrc} />
```

Comment: Most generic one would be https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error

Answer (score 10):

I would recommend you to use `SyntheticEvent<HTMLImageElement, Event>`

So you will be able to use it like this:

```
function addDefaultSrc(e: SyntheticEvent<HTMLImageElement, Event>) {
  e.currentTarget.src = "default.png";
}
```

Also, you can read more about `target` and `currentTarget` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5921413/difference-between-e-target-and-e-currenttarget)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question.

Answer (score 2):

```
   addDefaultSrc(event :Event)  {
      (event.target as HTMLImageElement).src = "default.png";
     }
```

Do it like this, and it will work.

Comment: *it is not recommended* to post code-only answers, answers should provide more explanation about the code to make the answer more useful and are more likely to attract upvotes