# React TypeScript get Data Attribute From Click Event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, custom-data-attribute

So I have a React component with a button which has a click handler which uses the data-* attribute. If this was straight React then I know how to get the value from the data-* attribute. However I am learning how to use TypeScript so I have no idea how to get access to this attribute. So what is the best way to get access to the data-* attribute using TypeScript?

This is my JSX code for the button:

```
<button type="button" className="NavLink" data-appMode={ AppMode.MAIN } onClick={ this.handleAppModeClick.bind(this) }>Main</button>
```

This is my handler for the click event:

```
handleAppModeClick(e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) {
    // What code should go here to access the data-appMode attribute?
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Use e.currentTarget** and then use HTML standard method `getAttribute`. No coercion necessary.

```
const appMode = e.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-appmode');
```

(note lowercase in the attribute name to avoid warnings from react)

### `currentTarget` is already correctly typed.

If you read [the definitions of React's event types](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/index.d.ts#L485) you can see that `MouseEvent` extends `SyntheticEvent`, which extends `BaseSyntheticEvent`, which includes the property `target` and `currentTarget`, among others. The `HTMLElement` type you provide gets applied to `currentTarget`, so you have access to all the right stuff. If you use `target` you'll get a compile error about `getAttribute` not being valid for type `EventTarget`.

### What's the difference?

The `currentTarget` is the element where you're putting your handler, `onClick`. The `target` is where the event originally came from ([more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5921413/difference-between-e-target-and-e-currenttarget)). This is not necessarily the same because events bubble up. See the [PR referenced in the type definitions file](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/12239) for a complete discussion on why they're typed differently.

Comment: Thanks Chris! I wasn't aware that there is currentTarget existing inside event together with regular target.

Comment: `currentTarget` does not work in case of Event Delegation pattern.

Answer (score 2):

You most likely will have to use `as` syntax , depending which property you want to access on e.target.

```
handleAppModeClick(e: React.MouseEvent) {
    const appMode = (e.target as HTMLButtonElement).getAttribute('data-appMode');
}
```

Comment: Coercion/as is unnecessary, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using typescript I've recently learnt of the following approach:

```
type TabsProps = {
  activeTab: string,
  items: string[],
  setActiveTab: (i: string) => void,
}

const Tabs = ({ items, activeTab, setActiveTab }: TabsProps) => {
  const onClick: React.MouseEventHandler<HTMLElement> = (e) => {
    setActiveTab(e.currentTarget.dataset.id)
    //console.log(e) // <a data-id="0" class="active nav-link">Info</a>
  }

  return (
    <Nav tabs >
        {
            items.map((x, i) => (
                <NavItem key={i}>
                    <NavLink className={activeTab === i.toString() ? 'active' : ''} onClick={onClick} data-id={i}>{x}</NavLink>
                </NavItem>
            ))
        }
    </Nav >
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your event function you have e variable, e represents an event fired by clicking the button, e has a target property so, in order to access an attribute from the element you should do:

```
handleAppModeClick(e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) {
    const target = e.target as HTMLElement;
    let attr = target.getAttribute("data-attribute-name-here");
    //do something

}
```

Comment: Nope that is for using straight React. I am using React with TypeScript which uses a different way. I get this error when I try your code: Property 'getAttribute' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.

Comment: Yeah you're right, you should cast the target first, mb.