# Get attribute value in click handler?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

How can I get the value of the `eventKey` attribute and pass it to my function in the following line?

```
<Accordion.Toggle 
   as={Card.Header} 
   eventKey="2" 
   data-foo="zzz" 
   onClick={(e) => CardClick(e.currentTarget.getAttribute('eventKey') ?? "unknown")}> // unknown.  Desired value: 2
```

The following is addressed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58634154/react-typescript-get-data-attribute-from-click-event). In my case however the attribute I need to get is not prefixed with "data-".

Works:

```
<Accordion.Toggle 
   as={Card.Header} 
   eventKey="2" 
   data-foo="zzz" 
   onClick={(e) => CardClick(e.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-foo') ?? "unknown")}> // zzz
```

Not works:

```
<Accordion.Toggle 
   as={Card.Header} 
   eventKey="2" 
   data-foo="zzz" 
   onClick={(e) => CardClick(e.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-eventKey') ?? "unknown")}> // unknown
```

Complete component:

```
<Card>
    <Accordion.Toggle as={Card.Header} eventKey="0" className="faq-header" onClick={(e) => CardClick(e.currentTarget.getAttribute('eventKey') ?? "unknown")}>
        <span className="rh5">Some text</span>
    </Accordion.Toggle>
    <Accordion.Collapse eventKey="0">
        <Card.Body>
            <span className="rh6">
                Some text
            </span>
        </Card.Body>
    </Accordion.Collapse>
</Card>
```

Comment: If the attribute exists in the HTML, just change `getAttribute('data-eventKey')` to `getAttribute('eventKey')`?

Comment: I tried what you suggested - please see last line in the question.

Comment: If it doesn't exist in the HTML, but rather is only known as a prop for the Accordion, you might have to write out the `"2"` twice, though that seems ugly. Better would be to change the component to render the attribute in the HTML too.

Comment: It may be because of your simplified example, but if the `eventKey` is hardcoded (as it appears to be) then why not just hardcode the same value out to `CardClick`?

Comment: If I don't have to I would rather not.  I want to understand the principal, and also I have a ton of these things to maintain and it's just ugly to do it that way.

Comment: @Sam Can you share the complete code for your component?

Comment: Yes, I think we need a bit more context because IMO you're already assigning the `eventKey` and anonymous `onClick` handler props manually so I don't quite understand why here is where you've drawn the line. My point is that at the moment when you are passing `eventKey` a value is the same time you are assigning an `onClick` callback to receive that value, so just pass to the callback the value you want it to have when invoked. This completely removes/cuts out a chunk of unnecessary logic and data wrangling.

Comment: I think it's fair to not want to hard code something twice.  This will not be the greatest length I've gone to too avoid doing it.  Also I just want to know how to do it.  Kind of like the mountain.... because it's there...

Comment: I guess? I think you are still missing the point that you don't need to *actually* pass any data to the element when you can instead just enclose it in the attached callback. Coded once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained by @DrewReese in the comments, it is impossible to get the `eventKey` from the DOM element (`e.target`) because it is never passed down to the DOM.

We should get it from the `props` instead.  We do need to use `eventKey` in three places: as the `eventKey` prop in both the `Toggle` and the `Collapse` and in our `onClick`.  But when it becomes abstracted out as a component prop, we only need to declare the specific event key, ie. `eventKey="2"`, once.

```
import React from "react";
import { Accordion, Card } from "react-bootstrap";

interface RenderCardProps {
  eventKey: string;
  CardClick: (key: string) => void;
  /** add whatever else you need */
}

const RenderCard = ({ eventKey, CardClick }: RenderCardProps) => {
  return (
    <Card>
      <Accordion.Toggle
        as={Card.Header}
        eventKey={eventKey}
        className="faq-header"
        onClick={() => CardClick(eventKey)}
      >
        <span className="rh5">Some text</span>
      </Accordion.Toggle>
      <Accordion.Collapse eventKey={eventKey}>
        <Card.Body>
          <span className="rh6">Some text</span>
        </Card.Body>
      </Accordion.Collapse>
    </Card>
  );
};

export default () => <RenderCard CardClick={console.log} eventKey="2" />;
```

You probably want to make `ToggleContents` and `CardContents` into props too in order to use this as an actual component.