# Javascript event.stopPropogation is still triggering for child element of a button

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to add event listeners to buttons on a webpage, my button contains several child elements, when I click my button I only need to get the data associated with the button, such as data attributes.

Even after adding an `event.stopPropogation()` into my on click handler, I'm still seeing that when I click directly over a `h2` element that there's no data attributes logged.

What am I exactly missing from my code?

```js
const button = document.querySelector('[data-toggle="collapse"]')

button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  e.stopPropagation()
  const target = e.target.dataset
  console.log(target)
}, false)
```

```html
<body>
  <button type="button" data-target="hello" data-toggle="collapse">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <h2>
        My heading 2
      </h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</button>
</body>
```

Comment: You have a serious misconception about how propagation works.  Please take a look at [Introduction to events - Bubbling and capturing explained](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#bubbling_and_capturing_explained)

Comment: `e.currentTarget.dataset`

Answer (score 0):

Stop propagation works the other way round. You can see how it works here: [What's the difference between event.stopPropagation and event.preventDefault?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963669/whats-the-difference-between-event-stoppropagation-and-event-preventdefault)

What you need to do is to get the data from e.currentTarget instead of e.target.

```
const button = document.querySelector('[data-toggle="collapse"]')
button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    const target = e.currentTarget.dataset
    console.log(target)
}, false);
```

Also: [Difference between e.target and e.currentTarget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5921413/difference-between-e-target-and-e-currenttarget)